# Rsync filter: copying one pattern only

Tags: backup, rsync, wildcards

I am trying to create a directory that will house all and only my PDFs compiled from LaTeX. I like keeping each project in a separate folder, all housed in a big folder called `LaTeX`. So I tried running:

```
rsync -avn *.pdf ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

which should find all the pdfs in `~/LaTeX/` and transfer them to the output folder. This doesn't work. It tells me it's found no matches for "`*.pdf`". If I leave out this filter, the command lists all the files in all the project folders under LaTeX. So it's a problem with the *.pdf filter. I tried replacing `~/` with the full path to my home directory, but that didn't have an effect.

I'm, using zsh. I tried doing the same thing in bash and even *with* the filter that listed every single file in every subdirectory... What's going on here?

Why isn't rsync understanding my pdf only filter?

---

OK. So update: No I'm trying

```
rsync -avn --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" LaTeX/ Output/
```

And this gives me the whole file list. I guess because everything matches the first pattern...

Comment: uh, you seem to be right... I think my answer (using zsh's `**` pattern) should work, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone tell me why rsync is no copying files from the source's subfolders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377496/can-anyone-tell-me-why-rsync-is-no-copying-files-from-the-sources-subfolders)

Answer (score 388, accepted):

TL,DR:

```
rsync -am --include='*.pdf' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

---

Rsync copies the source(s) to the destination. If you pass `*.pdf` as sources, the shell expands this to the list of files with the `.pdf` extension in the current directory. No recursive traversal happens because you didn't pass any directory as a source.

So you need to run `rsync -a ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/`, but with a filter to tell rsync to copy `.pdf` files only. Rsync's filter rules can seem daunting when you read the manual, but you can construct many examples with just a few simple rules.

- Inclusions and exclusions:

  - Excluding files by name or by location is easy: `--exclude=*~`, `--exclude=/some/relative/location` (relative to the source argument, e.g. this excludes `~/LaTeX/some/relative/location`).
  - If you only want to match a few files or locations, include them, *include every directory leading to them* (for example with `--include=*/`), then exclude the rest with `--exclude='*'`. This is because:
  - If you exclude a directory, this excludes everything below it. The excluded files won't be considered at all.
  - If you include a directory, this doesn't automatically include its contents. In recent versions, `--include='directory/***'` will do that.
  - For each file, the first matching rule applies (and anything never matched is included).
- Patterns:

  - If a pattern doesn't contain a `/`, it applies to the file name sans directory.
  - If a pattern ends with `/`, it applies to directories only.
  - If a pattern starts with `/`, it applies to the whole path from the directory that was passed as an argument to `rsync`.
  - `*` any substring of a single directory component (i.e. never matches `/`); `**` matches any path substring.
- If a source argument ends with a `/`, its contents are copied (`rsync -r a/ b` creates `b/foo` for every `a/foo`). Otherwise the directory itself is copied (`rsync -r a b` creates `b/a`).

---

Thus here we need to include `*.pdf`, include directories containing them, and exclude everything else.

```
rsync -a --include='*.pdf' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

Note that this copies all directories, even the ones that contain no matching file or subdirectory containing one. This can be avoided with the `--prune-empty-dirs` option (it's not a universal solution since you then can't copy a directory even by matching it explicitly, but that's a rare requirement).

```
rsync -am --include='*.pdf' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

Comment: In contrast to my solution (using zsh's `**` pattern), this recreates the directory structure in the target dir. I'm not sure whether this is what the OP wants...

Comment: @Michael I can't reproduce this. I just tried it with rsync 3.1.1 and rsync 3.1.3, between local directories, and it only lists maching files that are missing or different on the destination (and their directories).

Comment: Why the `-m` option?

Comment: @becko Because rsync has to traverse and copy all directories in order to find and copy all the .pdf files. The `-m` option tells it not to copy directory subtrees that turn out not to have any .pdf file to copy.

Answer (score 48):

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" --exclude="*" ~/Latex/ ~/Output/ --dry-run
```

The default is to include everything, so you must explicitly exclude everything *after* including the files you want to transfer.
Remove the --dry-run to actually transfer the files.

If you start off with:

```
--exclude '*' --include '*.pdf'
```

Then the greedy matching will exclude everything right off.

If you try:

```
--include '*.pdf' --exclude '*'
```

Then only pdf files in the top level folder will be transferred. It won't follow any directories, since those are excluded by '*'.

Comment: As of 2014-03-17 this is the best answer, as it solves the original posters question **exactly**. Please vote it up! If you add `--prune-empty-dirs` (or shortcut `-m`) you even spare yourself many empty directories at the destination, except of course you want them as a reminder or structural blueprint.

Comment: Best answer, --include="*/" is key.

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

If you use a pattern like `*.pdf`, the shell “expands“ that pattern, i.e. it replaces the pattern with all matches in the current directory. The command you are running (in this case rsync) is unaware of the fact that you tried to use a pattern.

When you are using **zsh**, there is an easy solution, though: The `**` pattern can be used to match folders recursively. Try this:

```
rsync -avn ~/LaTeX/**/*.pdf ~/Output/
```

Comment: Wouldn't that copy all pdfs from somewhere within the current directory *and* everything from ~/LaTeX/ to ~/Output?

Comment: I guess you meant `rsync -avn ~/LaTeX/**/*.pdf ~/Output`, but the solution with `--include` is more scalable anyway.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the command I mistyped in a rush... I agree that the include command (in SamB's version) is better, though it is a bit more complicated and specific to rsync while the `**` might become handy in other situations as well.

Comment: I was worried that this solution wouldn't work if you had some pdfs in `foo/` and some in `foo/bar/` and you wanted them all moved that wouldn't work, but it does work. I like this answer, but I do actually want to preserve folder structure as well, so this doesn't work. But I do like the zsh `**` trick, and I'm sure I'll use it in the future!

Comment: Bash 4 has adopted the same feature. Oh, and you don't need rsync here, cp will do. On some systems, if there are a lot of files, it helps to do `cd ~/Latex && cp -p **/*.pdf ~/Output` to avoid a “command line too long” error.

Comment: Note that rsync's patterns used in the include and exclude filters also have a ** that does the same thing.   You can escape *'s from other shells by putting them in quotation marks.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `find` and an intermediate list of files (`files_to_copy`) to solve your issue. Make sure you're in your home directory, then:

`find LaTeX/ -type f -a -iname "*.pdf" > files_to_copy && rsync -avn --files-from=files_to_copy ~/ ~/Output/ && rm files_to_copy`

Tested with Bash.

Comment: I think that find is the most robust solution, but I would opt for either using finds `-exec` option or using `xargs`. Something like: `find LaTeX/ -type f -iname "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -i rsync -avn {} Output/`

Comment: Yeah... I'd suggest find as well... though I imagine rsync *must* be able to do this.

Comment: This is a neat solution to a harder problem as well: presumably I could use this to exclude files whose document class is `standalone` or which don't have a `.tex` file with the same name, since these will be images included in some document...

Comment: rsync option `--files-from` accepts reading from stdin. This would work 
`find LaTeX/ -type f -a -iname "*.pdf" | rsync -avn --files-from=- ~/ ~/Output/`

Answer (score 8):

Judging by the "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" section of the [manpage](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), the way to do this is

```
rsync -avn --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" ~/Latex/ ~/Output/
```

The critical difference between this and kbrd's answer is the `--include="*/"` flag, which tells rsync to go ahead and copy any directories it finds, whatever they are named. This is needed because rsync will not recurse into a subdirectory unless it has been instructed to copy that subdirectory.

Also, note that the quotation marks prevent the shell from trying to expand the patterns to filenames relative to the current directory, and doing one of the following:

1. Succeeding and messing up your filter (not too likely in the middle of a flag like that, though you really never know when someone will make a file named `--include=foo.pdf` ...)
2. Failing, and potentially producing an error instead of running the command (as you've discovered zsh does by default).

Comment: So this will copy only the PDFs and the directory structure, while kbrd's will copy the files, but ignore the structure?

Comment: Hmm. This actually still seems to try and copy everything, I guess because that's what it does without the filter, so `include`ing extra stuff already in there doesn't change anything. If you see what I mean...

Comment: You need `--exclude="*"` after the `--include="*.pdf"`, or this will transfer everything.

Comment: @jmanning2k: Ah. Good to know!

Answer (score 6):

This is my preferred solution:

```
find source_dir -iname '*.jpg' -print0 |  rsync -0 -v --files-from=- . destination_dir/
```

The `find` command is easier to understand than the include/exclude rules of `rsync` :-)

If you want to copy only pdf files, just change `.jpg` to `.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
rsync -avn --include="*.pdf" ~/Latex/ ~/Output/
```

Comment: No, `man rsync` puts the filter after the options and before the source/destiinations. I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Your way finds .pdf files in the current folder, but not recursively, as I want. (the `a` option is for archive and among other things it makes the copying recursive.

Comment: Ooops, my bad. I updated my answer.

Comment: +1 for being so close, and giving me a clue about how to find the relevant material in the manual page. (Hopefully I even got it right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that should work without using find.  The difference from answers already posted is the order of the filter rules.  Filter rules in an rsync command work a lot like iptable rules, the first rule that a file matches is the one that is used.  From the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/rsync.1.html#toptoc14):

> As the list of files/directories to
>   transfer is built, rsync checks each
>   name to be transferred against the
>   list of include/exclude patterns in
>   turn, and  the
>          first matching pattern is acted on:  if it is an exclude pattern, then
>   that file is skipped; if it is an
>   include pattern then that filename is
>   not skipped; if
>          no matching pattern is found, then the filename is not skipped.

Thus, you need a command as follows:

```
rsync -avn --include="**.pdf" --exclude="*" ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

Note the "**.pdf" pattern.  According to [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/rsync.1.html#toptoc15):

> if the pattern contains a / (not counting a trailing /) or a "**", then it is matched against the full pathname, including any leading directories.  If
>                 the  pattern  doesn’t  contain  a  /  or  a "**", then it is matched only against the final component of the filename.  (Remember that the algorithm is
>                 applied recursively so "full filename" can actually be any portion of a path from the starting directory on down

In my small test, this does work recursively down the directory tree and only selects the pdfs.

Comment: How exactly did you test? According to my understanding of the documentation and my experimental verification, your command should only copy `*.pdf` in the toplevel directory (but not `~/LaTeX/foo/bar.pdf`).

Comment: @Gilles Crud. You are right. I swore I tested this and it worked, but I can't seem to recreate it.  And now that I actually read the man page that I quoted, it makes sense that it doesn't work.  Grumble.

Comment: Well, I figured out where my test was wrong.  My "small test" was on a directory that has .tex and .pdf files of my own.  I then created a "test" subdirectory and a test.pdf and test.tex in that subdir.  However, I failed to notice that there was a test.pdf in my top level dir, likely because of some quick one of LaTeX experiment I did.

Comment: I still don't understand the `**`. Would be nice to have example of it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In an update to @Giles' answer, please consider that the order of the include and exclude commands must be changed with current versions (>=3.x.x) to have the include options before the exlude options in order to build the correct file list. It is also my personal best practice to put the "include all subdirectories" instruction generally first and then the file pattern:

```
rsync -avh --include='*/' --include='file-pattern' --exclude='*' /sourcedir/ /targetdir/
```

i.e. in your case:

```
rsync -avh --include='*/' -include='*.pdf' --exclude='*' ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

Further explanation can also be drawn from the manual at https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html under the headline "FILTER RULES":

> Note that, when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subdir component of every path is visited left to right, with each directory having a chance for exclusion before its content. In this way include/exclude patterns are applied recursively to the pathname of each node in the filesystem's tree (those inside the transfer). The exclude patterns short-circuit the directory traversal stage as rsync finds the files to send.

> For instance, to include "/foo/bar/baz", the directories "/foo" and "/foo/bar" must not be excluded. Excluding one of those parent directories prevents the examination of its content, cutting off rsync's recursion into those paths and rendering the include for "/foo/bar/baz" ineffectual (since rsync can't match something it never sees in the cut-off section of the directory hierarchy).

> The concept path exclusion is particularly important when using a trailing '*' rule. For instance, this won't work:

```
+ /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
+ /file-is-included
- *
```

> This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the '*' rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the "some" or "some/path" directories. One solution is to ask for all directories in the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it somewhere before the "- *" rule), and perhaps use the --prune-empty-dirs option. Another solution is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited. For instance, this set of rules works fine:

```
+ /some/
+ /some/path/
+ /some/path/this-file-is-found
+ /file-also-included
- *
```

> Here are some examples of exclude/include matching:

```
"- *.o" would exclude all names matching *.o
"- /foo" would exclude a file (or directory) named foo in the transfer-root directory
"- foo/" would exclude any directory named foo
"- /foo/*/bar" would exclude any file named bar which is at two levels below a directory named foo in the transfer-root directory
"- /foo/**/bar" would exclude any file named bar two or more levels below a directory named foo in the transfer-root directory
The combination of "+ */", "+ *.c", and "- *" would include all directories and C source files but nothing else (see also the --prune-empty-dirs option)
The combination of "+ foo/", "+ foo/bar.c", and "- *" would include only the foo directory and foo/bar.c (the foo directory must be explicitly included or it would be excluded by the "*")
```

> The following modifiers are accepted after a "+" or "-":

```
A / specifies that the include/exclude rule should be matched against the absolute pathname of the current item. For example, "-/ /etc/passwd" would exclude the passwd file any time the transfer was sending files from the "/etc" directory, and "-⁠/ subdir/foo" would always exclude "foo" when it is in a dir named "subdir", even if "foo" is at the root of the current transfer.
A ! specifies that the include/exclude should take effect if the pattern fails to match. For instance, "-! */" would exclude all non-directories.
A C is used to indicate that all the global CVS-exclude rules should be inserted as excludes in place of the "-⁠C". No arg should follow.
An s is used to indicate that the rule applies to the sending side. When a rule affects the sending side, it prevents files from being transferred. The default is for a rule to affect both sides unless --delete-excluded was specified, in which case default rules become sender-side only. See also the hide (H) and show (S) rules, which are an alternate way to specify sending-side includes/excludes.
An r is used to indicate that the rule applies to the receiving side. When a rule affects the receiving side, it prevents files from being deleted. See the s modifier for more info. See also the protect (P) and risk (R) rules, which are an alternate way to specify receiver-side includes/excludes.
A p indicates that a rule is perishable, meaning that it is ignored in directories that are being deleted. For instance, the -C option's default rules that exclude things like "CVS" and "*.o" are marked as perishable, and will not prevent a directory that was removed on the source from being deleted on the destination.
An x indicates that a rule affects xattr names in xattr copy/delete operations (and is thus ignored when matching file/dir names). If no xattr-matching rules are specified, a default xattr filtering rule is used (see the --xattrs option).
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a directory containing only headers (../include) from inside the source directory:

```
rsync -avh --prune-empty-dirs --exclude="build" --include="*/" --include="*.h" --exclude="*" ./* ../include/
```

This excludes all empty directories and the directory `build`

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a solution that does **not** copy the original directly structure (ie dumps all pdf's into one directory).  This should work:

```
find SRC_DIR/ -type f | grep *.pdf | xargs -i cp {} DEST_DIR
```