# Delete extraneous files from dest dir via rsync?

Tags: rsync

Say I have

```
SRC 
  001.jpg
  002.jpg
  001.txt
  a.zip

DEST
  hello.jpg
```

`rsync -d --delete SRC:{*.jpg,*.txt} DEST`

It doesn't remove hello.jpg from DEST, any idea how to archive this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The reason your command isn't working is explained by the [manual page for rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/rsync.1.html) (emphasis added):

> --delete
>
> This  tells  rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but  only  for the directories  that  are  being synchronized.  **You must have asked rsync to send the whole directory (e.g. "dir" or "dir/")
>   without using  a  wildcard  for  the directory’s contents (e.g.
>   "dir/*") since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus 
>   gets a  request  to  transfer individual files, not the files’
>   parent directory.**  Files that are excluded from the transfer  are 
>   also excluded from being deleted unless you use the --delete-excluded option or mark the rules as only matching on  the  sending side
>                 (see the include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES
>   section).

Thus, when you run

```
$ rsync -d --delete SRC:{*.jpg,*.txt} DEST
```

the unwanted files in DEST are not being deleted because you haven't actually asked for a directory to be synced, but just for a handful of specific files.  To get the results you desire, try something like this:

```
rsync -d --delete-excluded --include '*.jpg' --include '*.txt' --exclude '*' SRC/ DEST/
```

Notice that the order of the include and exclude directives matter.  Essentially, each file is checked against the include or exclude patterns in the order that they appear.  Thus, files with .jpg or .txt extensions are synced since they match the "included" patterns before they match the excluded "*" pattern.  Everything else is excluded by the `--exclude '*'` pattern.  The `--delete-excluded` option ensures that even excluded files on the DEST side are deleted.

Comment: @Cheng, care to explain a bit more?  I'd be happy to update my answer if there is a problem/improvement.

Comment: It works. I guess. The --process things is confusing me, make me thought it was transfered again.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain a bit more.

Comment: @Cheng: I suspect you don't want the `--delete-excluded`. Without it, only `*.jpg` and `*.txt` may be deleted on the destination side. With it, unrelated files would be deleted as well. You may be interested in this [tutorial on rsync filters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503).

Comment: Thanks! For me I was missing the trailing slash on the source directory.

Comment: For me it was the "/*" at the end of the source path.