# Asking rsync to delete files on the receiving side that don't exist on the sending side, with exceptions on the receiving side

Tags: rsync

I have read these threads:

- [rsync --delete --files-from=list / dest/ does not delete unwanted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813907/rsync-delete-files-from-list-dest-does-not-delete-unwanted-files)
- [Delete extraneous files from dest dir via rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/delete-extraneous-files-from-dest-dir-via-rsync)

But, as far as I can tell (maybe I am missing something), they don't cover the following question:

How do you ask `rsync` to copy files and delete those on the receiving side that do not exist on the sending side, with exceptions? (e.g. don't remove a mercurial repository `.hg` on the  receiving side, even if there is no repository on the sending side).

### One possibility?

Borrowing from @Richard Holloway's answer below. Say I have the following line:

```
rsync -av --exclude=dont_delete_me --delete /sending/path /receiving/path
```

As far as I understand, this line would make `rsync` delete everything on the receiving path that does not exist on the sending path, except those things matched by `dont_delete_me`. My question now is: Would rsync keep files on the receiving side that are matched by `dont_delete_me` **even if nothing on the sending side matches `dont_delete_me`?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use `--delete` and `--exclude` together what is in the excluded location won't get deleted even if the source files are removed.

But that raises the issue that the folder won't be `rsync`'d at all. So you will need another `rsync` job to `sync` that folder.

Eg.

```
rsync -nav /home/richardjh/keepall/ /home/backup/richardjh/keepall/
rsync -nav --exclude=keepall --delete /home/richardjh /home/backup/richardjh
```

You could run these the other way around, but then it would delete all removed files and then replace them, which is not as efficient.

You can't do it as a one liner.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. Your answer is making me think that my original question may have been easier than I thought. If I use the  single line: `rsync -av --exclude=dont_delete_me --delete /sending/path /receiving/path`, wouldn't that make `rsync` delete everything on the receiving path that does not exist on the sending path, except things matched by `dont_delete_me`? Most importantly, would `rsync` keep things on the receiving side matched by `dont_delete_me` **even if nothing on the sending side matches `dont_delete_me`**? If that's the case, I think that's the only line I need, right?

Comment: You are correct but you will also not get new files and changes to the dont_delete_me folder if you do it in one line. If you don't want to sync changes and additions, then you can just use the --exclude flag as you described here.

Comment: @AmV Excluded files are not deleted by `--delete`, unless you explicitly specify `--delete-excluded`. See the description of `--delete` and `--delete-excluded` in the rsync manual.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the following solution works for my purposes:

```
rsync -r --exclude-from=do_not_send_to_dest --delete --exclude-from=do_not_modify_in_dest src/ dest
```

*(Note: Add the `-n` option to do a dry-run, and do not change `--delete` to `--delete-excluded`!)*

Running the command causes the following properties:

- The source `src` directory remains unmodified
- The destination `dest` folder matches the source folder except that:

  - items on the `do_not_send_to_dest` list are not sent to the destination, and
  - items on the `do_not_modify_in_dest` list are left unmodified in the destination.
- (Note: It's no problem for non-existent items to be listed in either of the "`do_not_`" files.)

**Explanation**

I guess as rsync reads the command line arguments from left to right, the `--delete` argument seems to cause rsync to internally "switch modes" (in a sense), allowing the second use of the `--exclude-from` option again but with a different meaning.

Caveat:

- If an item on the `do_not_send_to_dest` list already exists in the destination, then:

  - this command doesn't remove that item from the destination (unless the item is first removed from the source directory)
  - **Caution:** changing `--delete` to `--delete-excluded` will delete everything in the destination that is listed on either of your two lists.  xD  (Perhaps rsync was writen to be open / flexible, but has some with nuances?)

---

Lightly usage tested.

I am using "`rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30`".

Comment: There is a slight misconception in your understanding of `--exclude-from=XXX`.
It does not exclude files in the source (from), it simply excludes the files provided in the XXX file, whether from creation, modification or deletion.
You can include multiple files though, from which the exclusions are provided.