# Extract files with specific file extension and keep directory structure?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a lot of .CR2 and .ARW files mixed together in a directory structured by date (2016 has the folder 06 and 07 within it with a folder for each day in them. So a file could be located in 2016/06/03 for example).

I want to extract the .ARW files into a separate folder while keeping the structure. Is this possible?

That is, I want to have two 2016 folders with the same structure but in one, there should only be .ARW files and in one there should only be .CR2 files.

Comment: When you say "extract", you mean "move", right?

Comment: You cannot have two directories/files named the same, so you cannot have two 2016 dir

Comment: @tachomi You can have two directories with the same name as long as they aren't in the same directory. I keep `tmp/` directories all over the place for stuff that I don't plan to keep long.

Comment: @Dave I'm very agree with that, but the OP is not specifying he needs only for a while that dir and they could be in different directories

Comment: @tachomi It's also a bit ambiguous if the names are `2016` or just contain 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These rsync commands should do what you're looking for

This will do ARW

```
rsync -arvz --progress --include='*.ARW' --include="*/" --exclude="*" ./source-dir-2016 ./target-ARW-2016
```

And this will do CR2

```
rsync -arvz --progress --include='*.CR2' --include="*/" --exclude="*" ./source-dir-2016 ./target-CR2-2016
```

I used [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76237/rsync-certain-files-excluding-the-rest-ignoring-svn-directory-recursively) for a source of information.

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest an alternative using `find` `exec` and `cp --parents`

```
find ./ -name *.ARW -exec cp --parents {} /home/user/target-ARW-dir/ \;
find ./ -name *.CR2 -exec cp --parents {} /home/user/target-CR2-dir/ \;
```

The limitation of this is that it your working directory has to just above the file structure you want to copy.

---

An idea of what it does:

`find` find files

`./` the directory it will look in

`-name *.ARW` only list files that end in .ARW

`-exec` perform commands on the list of files returned

`cp --parents` copy and maintain the directory structure

`{}` expands to each of the files `find` reports, think of it like the `x` in `for x in $files`

`/home/user/target-ARW-dir/` just an example directory, you should change this to what you actually want

`\;` proper way to terminate a `find -exec` so that it acts like a for loop

Answer (score 0):

What about `cp` recursively the `2016` dir to a `2016_ARW` and `rm *.CR2` from that, then `rm *.ARW` from the main.

e.g.

```
user:~$ ls 2016/06/03/
file_one.ARW file_two.CR2 file_three.CR2 file_four.ARW file_five.ARW
user:~$ cp -R 2016 2016_ARW
user:~$ rm 2016_ARW/06/03/*.CR2
user:~$ rm 2016/06/03/*.ARW
user:~$ ls 2016/06/03/
file_two.CR2 file_three.CR2
user:~$ ls 2016_ARW/06/03/
file_one.ARW file_four.ARW file_five.ARW
```

Comment: The OP suggested that the directory structure is `YYYY/MM/DD/file.ARW`, so you probably want your `rm` to be more like `rm 2016_ARW/*/*/*.CR2` (wildcards for month, day, and filename)