# Rsync, include only certain files types excluding some directories

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I want to rsync only certain file types (e.g. `.py`) and I want to exclude files in some directories (e.g. `venv`).

This is what I have tried:

```
rsync -avz --include='*/' --exclude='venv/' --include='*.py' --exclude='*' /tmp/src/ /tmp/dest/
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

I also followed the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76237/rsync-certain-files-excluding-the-rest-ignoring-svn-directory-recursively) but it didn't help.

Comment: why do you need the initial `--include='*/'`?

Comment: How does one craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory probably because of the last exclude that excludes everything

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`venv/` needs to be excluded *before* `*/` is included:

```
rsync -avz --exclude='venv/' --include='*/' --include='*.py' --exclude='*' /tmp/src/ /tmp/dest/
```

The subtlety is that `rsync` processes rules in order and the first matching rule wins.  So, if `--include='*/'` is before `--exclude='venv/'`, then the directory `venv/` is included by `--include='*/'` and the exclude rule is never consulted.

#### Could we simplify this?

> Why do we need `--include='*/'` and `--exclude='*'`? Why isn't `--exclude=venv/ --include='*.py'` sufficient?

The default is to include files/directories.  So, consider:

```
rsync -avz --exclude='venv/' --include='*.py' source target
```

This would include everything except files or directories under `venv/`.  You, however, only want `.py` files.  That means that we have to explicitly exclude other files with `--exclude='*'`.

`--exclude='*'` excludes *both* files and directories.  So, if we specify `--exclude='*'`, then all directories would be excluded and only the `.py` files it the root directory would be found.  `.py` files in subdirectories would never be found because `rsync` does not look into directories that are excluded.  Thus, if we have  `--exclude='*'`, we need to precede it with `--include='*/'` to ensure that the contents of all directories are explored.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Just for my understanding, why do we need `--include='*/'` and `--exclude='*'`? Why only `--exclude=venv/ --include='*.py'` does not work?

Comment: @CentAu I just updated the answer with a discussion of that.

Comment: How does one craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory probably because of the last exclude that excludes everything.

Comment: Bookmarking! Especially for the subtlety. I cannot think of any other CLI utility where **the order of the flags matters** at all!

Comment: No need for `-z` as it's ignored when copying between two local (or apparently local) filesystems

Comment: @antortjim `find` uses an ordered selection mechanism (`-name '*.o' -delete` vs `-delete -name '*.o'`)

Comment: Probably I couldn't think of other CLIs because of my ignorance.. surely there are, thanks for pointing out that find is another such utility. It's confusing to the inexperienced, but that's how we learn :)