# How to exclude subdirectory from rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` to recursively sync a remote folder tree that looks something like this:

```
/folderA/a1/cache
/folderA/a1/cache/A1
/folderA/a1/cache/A2
/folderA/a1/somefolder
/folderA/a1/someotherfolder
/folderA/a2/somefolder/cache
/folderB/cache/
/folderB/b1/somefolder/cache
/folderB/b1/somefolder/yetanotherfolder/cache
/folderB/b1/somefolder/yetanotherfolder/cache/B1
/folderB/b1/somefolder/yetanotherfolder/cache/B2
```

I don't know what the folder tree will look like and it will change over time. So what I want to be able to do is recursively `rsync` the above but *exclude* the folder "cache" and any sub folders it contains:

```
/folderA/a1
/folderA/a1/somefolder
/folderA/a1/someotherfolder
/folderA/a2/somefolder
/folderB/
/folderB/b1/somefolder
/folderB/b1/somefolder/yetanotherfolder/
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also an [rsync filter tutorial](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You want the `--exclude` flag.  For example, a local rsync:

```
rsync -a --exclude cache/ src_folder/ target_folder/
```

It really is that simple -- that exclude rule will match a directory named `cache` anywhere in your tree.  The `/` at the end forces it to match directories, so it won't exclude a file named `cache`.

You can match on paths as well.  Given the following tree:

```
a1/cache/
b1/cache/
sub/a1/cache/
```

`--exclude a1/cache/` will match `a1/cache` and `sub/a1/cache` but not `b1/cache`.  And `--exclude /a1/cache/` will match only `a1/cache`.

There's a lot more that can be done with rsync filtering.  Look for `--exclude`, `--include`, `--filter`, and especially the "FILTER RULES" and "PATTERN MATCHING RULES" sections on the rsync man page:

https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html#FILTER_RULES

Comment: Doh!!. Thanks it is the simple answers that I like best :-)

Comment: What about not anywhere in the tree? Like, only exclude `a/cache`. **UPD** See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83403/29867)

Comment: Also `--exclude /cache/` (with the leading /) will only exclude `a/cache` directory, not any directory named `cache`.

Comment: Why `a/ b/` in the above command line, what does it mean?

Comment: @Danijel: `a/` is the directory we're syncing (or copying) from; `b/` is the directory we're syncing into.