# rsync exclude directory not working

Tags: rsync

I am running Fedora 17 64-bit and the `rsync --exclude=/home/ben/<dir>` is not working as expected.

I am trying to `rsync` my home directory to a thumb drive, but I want to exclude certainly directories that hold cache files and build files.  This is the command I'm using:

```
rsync --exclude=/home/ben/build/ --exclude=/home/ben/.ccache -arv /home/ben home-ben/
```

However, content from the `~/build` and `~/.ccache` is being copied by `rsync`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI my issue was using the list syntax `--exclude={'landing','studio'}` and I had a space after the `,`. The list must not contain any spaces.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Global `rsync` filter rules beginning with a leading `/` are *anchored* to the root of transfer.  Quoting from the "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" section of the man page:

> if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname. This is similar to a leading ^ in regular expressions. Thus "/foo" would match a name of "foo" at either the "root of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file's directory (for a per-directory rule).

In your command (`rsync ... -arv /home/ben home-ben/`), the file `/home/ben/foo` would be transferred to `home-ben/ben/foo`.  The root of transfer is `home-ben` and the correct filter path is `/ben/foo`.  Thus,

- to match `/home/ben/.ccache` you need a filter path of `/ben/.ccache`
- to match `/home/ben/build/` you need a filter path of `/ben/build/`

A more detailed explanation can be found in the "ANCHORING INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS" section of the [`rsync(1)` man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).

---

Note that simply leaving out the leading `/` is not necessarily what you want.  Quoting again from the same man page section:

> An unqualified "foo" would match a name of "foo" anywhere in the tree because the algorithm is applied recursively from the top down; it behaves as if each path component gets a turn at being the end of the filename. Even the unanchored "sub/foo" would match at any point in the hierarchy where a "foo" was found within a directory named "sub". See the section on ANCHORING INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERNS for a full discussion of how to specify a pattern that matches at the root of the transfer.

Thus a filter pattern of `build/` would match a build directory anywhere in `/home/ben`, even `/home/ben/many/sub/directories/build/`.

Comment: The key detail is that slashes matter.  If you append a slash to the end of the source directory (rsync -a source/ destination) it will copy the contents of source, otherwise `rsync -a source destination` copies the source directory itself to the destination.  This determines what the root of the transfer will be in order to inform the exclude expression.  The proper use of / in the exclude expression is then explained above.  Note in particular that `rsync --exclude='/dir1' source destination` won't exclude anything.

Answer (score 18):

**WARNING:** *Per @rubo77's comment below, this answer should only be used if you're willing to exclude these items everywhere in your source tree, not just at the root. See @jw013's answer above for a more thorough explanation.*

I think your `exclude` paths need to be relative to the source path. Can you try this instead?

```
rsync --exclude=build/ --exclude=.ccache -arv /home/ben home-ben/
```

Here's a test, for comparison:

```
/tmp$ tree src dest
src
├── a
└── b
dest
└── foo/

/tmp$ rsync -nav --exclude /tmp/src/b /tmp/src /tmp/dest
sending incremental file list
src/
src/a
src/b

$ rsync -nav --exclude b /tmp/src /tmp/dest
sending incremental file list
src/
src/a
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. With a relative exclude path you would exclude the pattern everywhere!

Comment: This post is correct. The matching is text-based, not file inode-based. Whatever path the output of the `--verbose` command shows is the format you have to use.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: What if the source path is '/' then absolute are the relative paths, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: From the rsync docu: "if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname." So if I understand correctly then @rubo77 s answer is correct instead of this one.

Comment: This solution worked to match EVERYWHERE, and was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Your exclude pattern would work, if you rsync the whole /home path i.e. without a trailing slash:

```
rsync --exclude=/home/ben/build/ --exclude=/home/ben/.ccache -arv /home home-all/
```

But better only rsync the content of the folder with a trailing slash:

```
rsync --exclude=/build --exclude=/.ccache -arv /home/ben/ home-ben/
```

You can use an ignore-list too, see:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this is the first time I've seen someone share this syntax, which was apparently introduced in rsync version 3.1.3.

```
rsync [other opts...] --exclude='*/exclude_dirname/' /src/ /dst/
```

Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/954813/144798

More discussion: https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

In order to exclude a specific folder with `rsync` you need to consider the relative path in the command. In you case:

```
rsync --exclude=/ben/build/ --exclude=/ben/.ccache -arv /home/ben home-ben/
```

where "ben" is the folder you are syncing.