# How to use rsync to backup a directory without git subdirectory

Tags: rsync, git, dropbox

I want to copy my `c` directory with all subdirectories excluding `./git` subdirectory. I do it using `rsync` :

```
echo "copy c and sh files "
rsync -a --include='*.c' --include='*.sh' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/c/ ~/Dropbox/Public/c
# remove .git directory = do not send it to dropbox. Thx to Tomasz Sowa
rm -rf ~/Dropbox/Public/c/.git
```

Can I do it better?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just add an explicit exclude for .git:

`rsync -a --exclude='.git/' --include='*.c' --include='*.sh' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/c/ ~/Dropbox/Public/c`

Another option is to create `~/.cvsignore` containing the following line along with any other directories you'd like to exclude:

`.git/`

Comment: It is specified how you should give the path for `--exclude`. If you have problems with it, [check out this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83403/136348).

Answer (score 50):

You can just use `rsync --cvs-exclude`. It also ignores `.git` directories.

But take care, that this also ignores directories called `core` as occurring in Magento source files.

Comment: This works for the top level `.git` directory but not for `.git` directories in submodules. It also does not ignore Git files like `.gitmodules`.

Comment: Note: this does not work with default rsync version on latest MacOS, which is 2.6.9 as of March 2023. To get a modern rsync where --cvs-exclude option has been expanded to also exclude .git you need a newer version of rsync.  "brew install rsync" will install 3.2.7 as of March 2023!