# How can I copy a subset of files from a directory while preserving the folder structure?

Tags: directory-structure, file-copy

I want to move some subset of files from dirA to dirB (let's say files with "blah" in the filename), but I want all the nested directories to be the same in the new location. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only)

Answer (score 10):

The magic of `rsync` filter rules:

```
$ rsync -av --filter="+ */" --filter="-! *blah*" /source /dest
```

Consult the `rsync` man page for the details on filter rules, but here's the condensed version for this particular need.

`--filter="+ */"` means "include everything that is a directory"

`--filter="-! *blah*` means "exclude everything that does NOT include blah in the filename"

Answer (score 4):

If you need to copy these files cp will do:

```
cd dirA
find . -iname "*blah*" | xargs -If cp --parents f dirB
```

Option `--parents` preserves subdirs - it creates the full directory path for the destination.

Comment: the syntax here is much more clear than rsync

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`rsync -ave 'ssh -p 22' --filter="+ */" --exclude="*_blah.blah" uid@555.55.555.55:/source/directory/ /destination/directory/`

The `-e` switch defines `rsync` transfer protocol with port as `-p 22`. Also, the trailing `/` slashes are important to let the program know it's dealing with directories.

Thanks @pdo for the extra hours in my work day!