# Copying files containing specific text preserving directory structure

Tags: grep, find, directory, cp

Using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450850/2326627), I can easily copy a file containing specific text from one folder to another. With the `-r` option I can also search inside directories recursively.

The result is that now I have a lot of files copied in the destination directory. What if I want to preserve the directory hierarchy while copying the files?

It's a lot like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33486/how-to-copy-only-matching-files-preserving-subdirectories) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/180853/how-to-copy-file-preserving-directory-path-in-linux) question, but with the added difficulty that I have to search for specific text inside the files.

FWIW, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you found [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33498/116972), there would be nothing else special.

```
$ cd /path/to/srcdir
$ grep -lr PATTERN . | tar -T - -cf - | tar -C /path/to/dstdir -xf -
```