# Unix cp wildcard with directory structure

Tags: scripting, cp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I copy a subset of files from a directory while preserving the folder structure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/how-can-i-copy-a-subset-of-files-from-a-directory-while-preserving-the-folder-st)

I have a bunch of directories like this:

```
/Artists/Example Name 1/Images/Lo-res/
/Artists/Example Name 2/Images/Lo-res/
/Artists/Example Name 3/Images/Lo-res/
```

I want to use the `cp` command to copy all the contents of all of the "Lo-res" directories to another location while keeping their preceding directory structure (the name and images directories) intact.

I've been trying this

```
cp -R /Artists/*/Images/Lo-res /New_Location/
```

But that just copies all the files into one new Lo-res folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That's what `cp` does. I think you need to use something else to get the effect you want, such as `tar`.

Comment: Check out `rsync` and its [filter rules](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Answer (score 0):

rsync -av /Artists/*/Images/Lo-res/ /New_location/

the trailing / characters on the source and destination directories are very important to rsync to attain the effect you want.