# How to include files that are excluded in an rsync

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to set up an rsync that excludes all `.*` files except for `.htaccess` but unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
rsync -avP --exclude=".*" --include="./.htaccess" ./. user@server:/dir
```

Is it possible to somehow exclude general exclude rules?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first matching rule applies, so include `.htaccess` before excluding `.*`.

```
rsync -avP --include=".htaccess" --exclude=".*" . user@server:/dir
```

This copies `.htaccess` at every level. I don't know what you intended with `./.htaccess`; if you want to match a file at the root of the copy only, start the pattern with a `/`. If you only want the root `.htaccess`, you can't just use `--include='/.htaccess' --exclude='.*'`, because the non-rooted rule actually takes precedence here, you need to do something more complicated:

```
rsync -avP --exclude='/*/**/.htaccess' --include='.htaccess' --exclude=".*" . user@server:/dir
```

Further reading: [basic principles for rsync filters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503).

Comment: @fred.bear: That one was a genuine typo, and a nasty one. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Thanks, I had tried putting the `--include` first, but the "./" in front of the "./.htaccess" was what was killing it.

Comment: @Rich note that if there are hidden directories that contain a `.htaccess` file, you'll have to `--include='.*/'` (I think) before the final `--exclude`, see also [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2503/863)

Comment: Any idea why `rsync -avP --exclude=/.htaccess src/dir/ dst/dir/` works as expected (excludes `.htaccess` only at the root directory), but `rsync -avP --exclude=/.htaccess src/dir dst` doesn't (it fails to exclude even at the root)?

Comment: @haridsv In the first case, the root is `src/dir` and you're copying the root, so `src/dir/.htaccess` is excluded. In the second case, the root is `src` and you're copying `dir`, so `src/.htaccess` is excluded.

Comment: You are right! This works: `rsync -avP --exclude=/dir/.htaccess src/dir dst`