# rsync an mpd playlist

Tags: rsync

An mpd playlist looks like this:

syncrel.m3u

```
Bob Dylan - The Times They Are A-Changin' [V0]/04. One Too Many Mornings.mp3
Bob Dylan - The Times They Are A-Changin' [V0]/01. The Times They Are A-Changin'.mp3/
```

Or it can be configured to store the full path:

syncfull.m3u

```
/home/share/media/audio/Bob Dylan - The Times They Are A-Changin' [V0]/01. The Times They Are A-Changin'.mp3
/home/share/media/audio/Bob Dylan - The Times They Are A-Changin' [V0]/03. With God On Our Side.mp3
```

I want to `rsync` those files to /media/sdg/MUSIC. I want it to delete files from the destination if they get removed from the playlist.

I can not get the incantation right. I thought I had it last night, but when I reran it, it didn't work. I've tried every combination of `include-from`, `exclude=*`, etc. I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic approach (see [this rsync filter guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) for more information):

- include the files in the playlist;
- include all directories (otherwise nothing would be copied), and exclude everything else;
- delete non-synced files and empty directories

Thus (untested):

```
rsync -a --include-from=/path/to/syncrel.m3u --include='*/' --exclude='*' \
      --delete --delete-excluded --prune-empty-dirs \
      /home/share/media/audio/ /media/sdg/MUSIC
```

If your file names may contain one of the wildcard characters `*?[`, there's an added complication. You need to precede these characters with a backslash. And if there are backslashes in file names as well, you need to precede them with a backslash as well, but only if there are other wildcards. Here's a sed snippet to convert a list of file names to the expected format (you only need the first expression if there are no backslashes in the file names):

```
sed -e 's/[*?\[]/\\&/g' -e 's/[*?[]/&/' -e T -e 's/\\\\/\\/g'
```

Under bash, ksh or zsh, there's a convenient way to filter the file list before passing it to rsync:

```
rsync -a --include-from=<(</path/to/syncrel.m3u sed -e 's/[*?\[]/\\&/g') \
      --include='*/' --exclude='*' \
      --delete --delete-excluded --prune-empty-dirs \
      /home/share/media/audio/ /media/sdg/MUSIC
```

Comment: thanks! this works, but it is silently skipping songs in certain albums(even with -v). I think it's the square brackets in the directory name. Adding -s doesn't solve. (Can someone  fix my comment? Or should  this go somewhere else?)

Comment: @tladuke: rsync is interpreting the `[` as a pattern character. See my edited answer. (To remove your first comment, click the `×` button that appears when you hover the mouse above it.)

Comment: how have I never seen _that_ before (that shell magic)

Comment: adding --modify-window=1 because the destination is FAT and rsync re-syncs sometimes

Comment: @Gilles I had to use `sed -e 's/[*?\[]/\\\\&/g')` to make the above work, otherwise it was skipping the files such as `Album [2014]/01.hip-hop.mp3`