# rsync pattern copy: dotfiles

Tags: rsync, wildcards

I followed the advice given in the question
[Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only) to setup a command line I need to backup only the dotfiles `.inF*`

Yet with the command:

```
rsync -av --include='.inF*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /0ale/ \
   root@lambda2:/0ale/
```

I obtain that the directory structure gets mirrored, but no dotfile is copied.
The same command with a test pattern

```
rsync -av --include='test*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /0ale/ \
    root@lambda2:/0ale/
```

correctly copies the `test1.txt` file so it is a problem with dotfiles only. Any hints?

Comment: Does perhaps the `.` at the beginning get treated as a `merge` directive rather than being seen as part of the file name? You may want to try `+ .inF*` instead. Maybe use `--filter` with appropriate flags rather than include/exclude. See the rsync man page for details.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: A leading dot is only interpreted as a merge pattern flag if it is separated from the pattern by a space.

Answer (score 3):

The include/exclude filters in `rsync` are processed in the order in which they appear. In order to match a dot-file in a subdirectory (or any directory other than the current working directory of `rsync`) you need to place your `*/` include rule to include folders first, then your `.*` match to include dot-files.

```
rsync -av  --include='*/' --include='.inF*' --exclude='*' /0ale/ \
   root@lambda2:/0ale/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried something similar to the answer above to copy dotfiles (pattern was: `--include='.**' --exclude='*'`), but found that some other excludes that I wanted were not actually being excluded.

If you have other `--exclude=` flags you want to pass, use the following pattern:

```
rsync  -avz --exclude='path/to/exclude1' --exclude='path/to/exclude2' --exclude='.Trash'  /0ale/.[^.]* root@lambda2:/0ale/
```