# How to exclude numeric directories with rsync?

Tags: rsync, wildcards

I know rsync has an `--exclude` option which I use quite frequently. But how can I specify that it should exclude all "numeric" directories?

In the directory listing below I would like to only have it copy `css`,`html`,and `include`

```
.
..
123414
42344523
345343
2323
css
html
include
```

Normally my syntax is something like

`rsync -avz /local/path/ user@server:/remote/path/ --exclude="cache"`

I think it should look something like  `--exclude="[0-9]*"` but I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rsync's exclude option doesn't really support regex, it's more of a shell globbing pattern matching.

If those directories are fairly static, you should just list them in a file and use `--exclude-from=/full/path/to/file/exclude_directories.txt`.

**Updated to provide example**

First, you just put the directories into a file:

```
find . -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]*$' -print > /tmp/rsync-dir-exlcusions.txt
```

or

```
( cat <<EOT
123414
42344523
345343
2323
EOT ) > /tmp/rsync-directory-exclusions.txt
```

then you can do your rsync work:

```
rsync -avHp --exclude-from=/tmp/rsync-directory-exclusions.txt /path/to/source/ /path/to/dest/
```

You just need an extra step to set up the text file that contains the directories to exclude, 1 per line.

Keep in mind that the path of the directories in the job, is their relative path to how rsync sees the directory.

Comment: You could use a script which uses a regex to create this file before running the rsync

Comment: Could you give an example as an answer?

Comment: just updated to include an example, including what @RoryAlsop suggested combined with what thiton suggested below.

Comment: @TimKennedy In the file containing excludes, does rsync understand line-changes or space is enough?

Comment: @Abhinav `rsync` understands one entry per line.  spaces will not work.

Answer (score 11):

You can't say “a name that contains only digits” in rsync's pattern syntax. So include all names that contain a non-digit and exclude the rest.

```
rsync --include='*[!0-9]*' --exclude='*/' …
```

See also my [rsync pattern guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line:

```
rsync -avHp --exclude-from=<(cd /path/to/source; find . -type d -regex './[0-9]*' | sed -e 's|./||') /path/to/source/ /path/to/dest/
```

Comment: Haa the power of the shell :)

Answer (score 1):

Use find to make a list of the directories to be excluded, then use rsync's --exclude-from option as Tim Kennedy described it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
$> rsync -avlH --exclude=*.ibd --exclude-from=<(ls -p | grep -v / | \
   grep -E 'ibdata|ib_logfile')  /mnt/myfuse/ /u01/my3309/data/
```

Comment: That excludes InnoDB files -- not numeric directories.