# rsync with absolute paths and excluding subpaths

Tags: zsh, rsync

Say I have the following structure on path `origin_path`

```
origin_path/X=1/A/...
origin_path/X=1/B/...
origin_path/X=1/C/...
...
origin_path/X=2/A/...
origin_path/X=2/B/...
origin_path/X=2/C/...
...
...
```

I would like to replicate the structure above at a different path called     `destination_path`, but **only** including the paths corresponding to the directories **B** above.

In other words, I would like to get the following at `destination_path`

```
destination_path/X=1/B/...
destination_path/X=2/B/...
destination_path/X=3/B/...
...
```

To clarify, some of this structure in destionation path might exist already (e.g. the folders `destination_path/X=*`).

From what I understand, thanks to @Gilles' comment, `rsync` filters may be a great fit for this. However, I have never used them before and it's a bit hard for me to extrapolate the example provided in [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only) to my situation.

In what order should I include or exclude things in my case? And how do I tell rsync to use `origin_path` and `destination_path` as global paths? (as opposed to having it copy things with relative paths)

Comment: Is [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/2503) the same problem? If not, please update your question to explain the difference (I'm not sure exactly what your selection criteria are).

Comment: Thanks @Guilles. From what I understand, I think `rsync` filters are a great fit for this. I went through your answer and read about them a bit more online, but I am not sure how what would be the right rule here. I'll clarify my question too.

Comment: I have updated my answer @Gilles. I hope what I am asking for is much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
rsync --recursive --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*/B/**' --exclude '**' origin_path/ destination_path/
```

The first rule includes all directories (otherwise rsync won't descend into the top level directories). The second rule includes everything in a "B" subdirectories. The third rule excludes everything else. The `--prune-empty-dirs` option ignores empty directories (since we're including all directories with the first rule).