# How to copy some, but not all files?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

So, you can use the `*` as a wild card for all files when using `cp` within context of a directory.  Is there a way to copy all files except `x` file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In `bash` you can use `extglob`:

```
 $ shopt -s extglob  # to enable extglob
 $ cp !(b*) new_dir/
```

where `!(b*)` exclude all `b*` files.

You can later disable `extglob` with

```
 $ shopt -u extglob
```

Comment: Do you know if there's something equivalent for the tcsh shell?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Seems like `find` is the only way in `tcsh`: `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "exclude*" -exec cp -t destination {} \+`

Answer (score 72):

Rsync handles this nicely.

Example copy all: `rsync -aP /folder1/* /folder/2`

Example copy all with exclusion: `rsync -aP --exclude=x /folder1/* /folder2/`

The `-aP` switch:

- `a`: Similar to `cp -a`, recursive, etc.
- `P`: Shows progress, a nice feature of rsync.

Comment: And see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) for a short guide to common rsync exclusion lists.

Comment: On darwin/MacOS, use `-rP` instead of `-aP` if you want to recurse. `-a` is for archiving. Not sure if this changed or if it's just different on MacOS.

Comment: `rsync` does have the option to make it recursive. Example: `rsync --recursive -P --exclude=x /folder1/* /folder2/`.  (Tested only on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 13):

This isn't a feature of `cp`, it's a feature of your shell (it expands the `*` to mean all non-dot files), so the answer depends on which shell you're using. For example, `zsh` supports this syntax:

```
$ cp ^x /path/to/destination
```

Where `^x` means "all files except `x`"

You can also combine selection and de-selection patterns, e.g. to copy all wav files except those containing xyz, you can use:

```
cp *.wav~*xyz*
```

Comment: Any comments on `bash`?

Comment: @hydroparadise I don't know much about bash, but [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41696/73) seems to cover it

Comment: What about tcsh? Anyone know?

Answer (score 6):

Could also be done in plain old (portable/compatible) bourne shell in a variety of ways with standard tools in a lot less elegant ways than using advanced shell globbing or commands with built-in-exclusion options.

If there are not too many files (and not with names including spaces and/or linebreaks), this could be a way:

```
cp `ls | egrep -v '^excludename$'` destdir/.
```

Sure, `bash` and GNU tools are great and powerful, but they're still not always available. If you intend to put it in a portable script, I would recommend `find` as in the comment by Rush.

Comment: I find that the last part of your answer just distracts from the topic at hand.

Besides, "Unix" isn't the gold standard anymore (if it ever were). It just isn't that relevant if something is "Unix" or not anymore, despite the title of this site being "Unix and Linux".

Comment: OK. I moved the comment to here instead: Unix is not GNU. I agree that the "unixness" of things is not very interesting, but I still believe in portability and knowing a bit about your history.

Comment: Fully agree with you there.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy everything in a folder (including subfolders) to a particular sub-directory:

```
cp -R $(ls | grep -v '^subdir$') subdir/
```

Works with sh, bash, zsh (at least).

Comment: Convince me this isn't the same intention as `cp -R * subdir/`

Comment: If you use that command "cp -R * subdir/", bash/zsh tried to copy 'subdir' recurvively. You end up with an error: "name too long (not copied)".

Comment: Good point. Your suggestion attempts to avoid the warning from `cp` (not from `bash`/`sh`), "`cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘subdir’, into itself, ‘subdir/subdir’`". The copy does complete correctly, though. Unfortunately your variant breaks with any filename containing a space or shell-sensitive punctuation. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943

Answer (score 4):

The best and simple way is using `find`. Go to the source directory. Then use the following commands.

```
find . ! -name "*.log" | xargs -i cp -r {} ~/destination_dir
```

This copies all files except "*.log" files.

Comment: Note that find recursively searches all subdirectories by default, so using `cp -r` is causing to recurse twice on each file. Either use `find` with `-maxdepth 0` or remove `-r` from the `cp`.

Comment: Suggestion to exclude both the `-r` on `cp` as well as to limit find result to files only:  `find . -type f ! -name "*.log" | xargs -i cp {} ~/destination_dir`

Answer (score -2):

`extglob` is the best way so far I guess.

Another way is using
`cp $(ls --ignore=x) subdir/`

Comment: This will break given any form of special characters whatsoever in the filenames.  (Spaces, newlines, `$`, etc.)  Never parse the output of `ls`.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943