# Copying files with multiple extensions

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, cp

I would like to copy files with multiple extensions to a single destination directory.

For example, I can use the following command to copy all **.txt** files in the working directory to a directory called `destination`:

```
cp -v *.txt destination/
```

And I can use the following to copy all **.png** directories in the working directory to `destination`:

```
cp -v *.png destination/
```

But it's time consuming to type these as separate commands (even with the use of command history). **So, is there any way that I can tell `cp` to copy files with either the pattern `*.txt` *or* the pattern `*.png` to `destination`?**  Ideally, I would like to be able to specify more than two patterns -- like instructing `cp` to copy all `*.txt` *or* `*.png` *or* `*.jpg` files to `destination`, for example.

I'm sure that all of this is possible using a shell script -- I'm using `bash`, for example -- but is there any way to accomplish it more simply, just from the console?  Could I somehow use brace expansion to do it?

I know that it is possible to [copy all files in the working directory except those matching certain specified patterns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41693/how-to-copy-some-but-not-all-files?rq=1), but since my working directory contains far more file extensions that I ***don't*** want to copy than those I *do*, that would be a pain.

Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: `cp -v *.txt *.png destination/`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Brace expansion will get the job done.  `man bash` and search for `Brace Expansion`.

```
cp *.{txt,jpg,png} destination/
```

**EDIT:**

In keeping with the OP's request, the command above was missing the verbose option:

```
cp -v *.{txt,jpg,png} destination/
```

Comment: Can I do this on Windows?

Comment: If I do `cp data/images/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,mp4} destination/` and an `mp4` file does not exist, I get a `No such file or directory` error which breaks the script. Can I make the multiple extensions gracefully handle any missing formats?

Comment: @BradGreens You should really post a new question rather than asking here in the comments.  Your question may even have an answer already.  Posting a new question will not only get you an answer but it will then be searchable by others who need the same help.

Comment: @BradGreens Try redirecting standard error to the null device `cp -v *.{txt,jpg,png} destination/ 2>/dev/null` which doesn't affect standard output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in /Photos/directory/* ; do
    filenameWithoutPath="${filename##*/}"
    first_num="${filenameWithoutPath%%.*}"
    last_num="${filenameWithoutPath##*.}"
    cp $filename /Photos/directory/$first_num-$last_num.jpg
done
```

Thats working!