# How to copy files with multiple extensions in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, cp

This syntax of copying files with multiple extensions (per [Copying files with multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157286/copying-files-with-multiple-extensions)) works fine in a regular desktop environment:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/baz && cd /tmp/baz
$ touch /tmp/file.foo
$ touch /tmp/file.bar
$ cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
$
```

But this doesn't seem to work in a dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7 as base
RUN touch /tmp/file.foo
RUN touch /tmp/file.bar
RUN cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
```

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run -it tmp:tmp
[+] Building 4.0s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 149B                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [2/4] RUN touch /tmp/file.foo                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 => [3/4] RUN touch /tmp/file.bar                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./                                                                                                                                       1.5s
------
 > [4/4] RUN cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./:
#7 0.844 cp: can't stat '/tmp/*.{foo,bar}': No such file or directory
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./]: exit code: 1
```

Oddly, if I enter a running container, the exact same `cp` syntax works fine.

**How can I copy files with multiple extensions in a Dockerfile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in [a Dockerfile `RUN` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) are run using `/bin/sh`, which may not support brace expansion (the post you refer to explicitly talks about `bash`).

You can try any of the following:

1. Set `bash` as the shell for `RUN` using [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) (assuming you already have bash installed in the base image or using a previous `RUN` instruction):

   ```
   SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
   RUN cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
   ```
2. Call bash explicitly:

   ```
   RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cp /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./"]
   ```
3. Just not use brace expansion at all:

   ```
   RUN cp /tmp/*.foo /tmp/*.bar ./
   ```

---

> Oddly, if I enter a running container, the exact same `cp` syntax works fine.

Your running container might be running bash as the default shell. This needn't always be the case:

```
% docker run --rm -it alpine:3.7
/ # echo /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
/tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
/ # exit
% docker run --rm -it ubuntu:20.04
root@f184619a1121:/# echo /tmp/*.{foo,bar} ./
/tmp/*.foo /tmp/*.bar ./
root@f184619a1121:/# exit
%
```