# How to I copy the directory and subfolders but ignore certain files in the subfolder?

Tags: cp, file-copy, recursive

I believe the question is best asked with an example.

```
/home
   test1.txt
   test2.txt
   /home/my-folder
      test3.txt
      test4.txt
```

1. `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` and `my-folder` folder are inside `/home`.
2. `test3.txt` and `text4.txt` are inside `/home/my-folder`.

**I want to copy all the contents of `/home` folder but exclude the 2 files (`test3.txt` and `test4.txt`) inside `my-folder`.**

How can I do it using `cp`?

I know it's possible with `rsync` as I just tried it but there are times when `rsync` is not installed in a server and I don't have rights to install software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy some, but not all files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41693/44425)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with `find(1)` and `cpio(1)`:

```
find /home -path './my-folder/test[34].txt' -prune -o \( -type f -print \) | \
    cpio -pdamv /some/other/dir
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there's only the one, and some people just downvote a pipe - which might be why. But I'm curious - I though you could only prune a directory - does your use of the `-path` primitive enable you to also `-prune` explicit or even globbed filenames as well? Cause that's pretty damn cool, if so.

Comment: @mikeserv My understanding is `-prune` removes selected nodes from a tree, it doesn't matter if the nodes are terminals or not.  Pruning file globs certainly works fine with both GNU find and BSD find.

Comment: So... are you not going to do the [getting to know you](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2668/52934) thing? It's cool if you don't.

Comment: You know, this isn't the first exchange of yours where I've you explicitly referred to yourself as a human. Most people tend to take that kind of thing for granted.  I consider those that don't *very suspicious.* So out w/ it already - are you a robot?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with `cp` alone, short of listing the files to copy. Making partial copies goes beyond `cp`'s capabilities.

Rsync is the obvious tool for the job and it's very widespread.

If you only have POSIX tools, you can use [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html). You can omit files by rewriting their path to an empty string.

```
cd /home && pax -rw -pe -s'~^\./my-folder/test[34]\.txt$~~' . /path/to/destination
```

If you have only a minimal Linux server that lacks `pax`, see if its traditional equivalents `cpio` or `tar` are available. See [lcd047's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212726) for a `cpio` example. With GNU `tar`, you can do

```
mkdir /path/to/destination
tar -cf - -C /home --exclude='./my-folder/test[34].txt' . |
  tar -xf - -C /path/to/destination
```

Comment: what if I want to exclude all files with the txt extension? or perhaps a combo of .txt and .tmp? Thanks again :)

Comment: @mrjayviper Then make the pattern `*.txt`. To ignore `*.tmp` as well, add a second `-s` or `--exclude` argument, you can have as many as you like.

Answer (score 1):

## Rsync

I was in need of something like this and dive a bit on the forums. As mentioned from Gilles, I find that the best way is to use RSYNC. Two things that I like about it:

- You can use an external file like .gitignore as an input to exclude the files and folders you don't want to copy over.
- it's efficiency when you need to do repeat the same backup(copy) of the same source directory(you don't need to copy existing files or folders) as I will mention below in Example 4.

Example 1: Exclude a specific file:

```
rsync -a --exclude 'file.txt' originalDirectory/ backupDirectory/
```

Example 2: Exclude a specific folder(e.g. named dirName):

```
rsync -a --exclude 'dirName' originalDirectory/ backupDirectory/
```

Example 3: Exclude multiple files and folders:

```
rsync -a --exclude={'file1.txt', 'file2.json','dir1/*','dir2'} originalDirectory/ backupDirectory/
```

Example 4: Exclude multiple files and folders:

```
rsync -a --exclude-from='exclude.txt' originalDirectory/ backupDirectory/
```

**exclude.txt** contains the following:

```
file1.txt
file2.json
file3.pdf
dir1
dir2
*.png
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
cp !(my-folder) /foo
```

Example:

```
$ find . -type f
./my-folder/test4.txt
./my-folder/test3.txt
./test2.txt
./test1.txt
$ echo cp !(my-folder) /foo
cp test1.txt test2.txt /foo
$
```

Comment: This (1) assumes `bash`, (2) doesn't descend into subdirectories, and (3) omits `my-folder` completely, not just the two files.