# Copy directory but exclude files with certain names

Tags: bash, backup, cp

I'm not allowed to use rsync on the cluster I'm working on so I need to use things like `cp` or `tar` or `find` etc. I want to copy a large directory including all files and subfolders etc. while ignoring, i.e. not copying any files that for example have the names "file1", "file2" or "file3".

I saw [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472692/how-to-copy-a-directory-structure-but-only-include-certain-files-using-windows)
which allows me to *include* only certain files. I want basically that but I want to *exclude* certain files.

I also tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212723/how-to-i-copy-the-directory-and-subfolders-but-ignore-certain-files-in-the-subfo)
but when I tried a command using `tar` which was suggested there I get the error `tar: This does not look like a tar archive` and `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`

I also tried `cp !(filename-to-ignore) new_dir/` from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41693/how-to-copy-some-but-not-all-files) but this doesn't copy the subfolders.

I'm a beginner with bash so if you could explain your answer and what the flags etc. do that would really be helpfull, I've been trying forever now, on what I think shouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: It's difficult to come up with good solutions when we don't know what's "allowed" on your cluster. Running `rsync` would be easiest, even if it meant installing it as a non-root user in your home directory. Contact the admin(s) of the cluster. They likely have a standard way of performing backups or can suggest a way for you to get data off of the cluster in the way you want it. Many backup tools have exclusion options, like `--exclude` in `restic` etc.  It is their job to help you, the user of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU or libarchive's `tar`:

```
(cd src && tar --exclude='file[123]' -cf - .) |
  (cd dst && tar -xpf -)
```

Beware that GNU `tar` doesn't preserve the sparseness of files and depending on the version (or OS as some OS have some patches for that), not all extended attributes. `libarchive`'s `tar` (often called `bsdtar`) does preserve extended attributes and the `-S` option upon extraction can be used to create sparse files.

That runs two subshells piped to each other. The first one generates a `tar` stream that represents the `.` (current) directory and all its contents recursively but ignoring the files whose name matches the `test[123]` pattern (similar to shell glob patterns, not regexps, here `test` followed by a character in the {1, 2, 3} set) after having `c`hanged the subshell's current working `d`irectory with `cd`. And the second has `tar` extract that stream on the fly in its own working directory (`dst`).

GNU `tar` also has a `-C` option to do that `chdir()` internally, as [shown by Gilles in the Q&A you linked](/a/212755) (there was a missing `.` in there which I've now added and explains your error), though that has little advantage over using the `cd` of your shell.

See also [`info -n exclude tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#exclude) with GNU `tar` for the many different ways you can exclude files there and more generally [`info -n choosing tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Choosing.html#Choosing) to tune how files are selected/included in the archives it generates or extracts.

Comment: If your list of exclusions does not follow convenient patterns, or is unwieldy, there is an option `--exclude-from=myFile` that takes many patterns from your specified file.