# rsync all directories that start with a specific digit

Tags: rsync, wildcards, file-copy

I have directory loaded with thousands of sub directories:

```
/home/tmp/
          1
          12
          123
          1234
          2345
          234
          3456
          345
          34
```

Each subdirectory in turn has hundreds of subdirectories that I want to rsync if the first level subdirectory matches...

What I need is a way to copy/rsync only the directories that start with a given digit [1-9]...

What I think I want is basically something that would allow me to use wild cards to match

```
rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1* /home/tmp/
```

I want rsync to sync up the

```
/home/tmp/1/
/home/tmp/12/
/home/tmp/123/
/home/tmp/1234/
```

directories and any child subdirectories they have but not any of the first level directories that start with a different digit...

```
/home/tmp/234/
/home/tmp/2345/
........./3*/
........./4*/ etc..
```

**What I've tried:**

```
rsync -rzvvhP --exclude='*' --include-from=1.txt remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

where 1.txt contains:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

When I do this with 2.txt though rsync still seems to run through all the directories that start with 1 and 3 etc...

How can I do this so that I can have one command to rsync only the directories that start with any given digit?

Comment: I don't know if that's your problem, but you may want to protect the asterisk from local shell expansion (before it even gets to rsync). `'remotehost:/home/tmp/1*'` rather than without the single quotes.

Comment: What is wrong with `rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1* /home/tmp/`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you proposed should actually work:

```
rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1\* /home/tmp/
```

(You can get away with not quoting the `*` in most circumstances, as the pattern `remotehost:/home/tmp/1\*` is unlikely to match any file so it will be left alone with most shell setups.)

Your attempt with `--exclude='*'` failed because the first match applies, and your first match for everything (`*`) says to exclude.

See [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) for some general principles about rsync filters. Here, to include only directories beginning with `1` at the toplevel, and copy everything in included subdirectories, include `/1` then exclude `/*`.

```
rsync -rzvvhP --include='/1' --exclude='/*' remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

Comment: `rsync -rzvvhP --size-only --filter="+ /4*/" --exclude='/*'` ... is what I ended up using...the issue I believe the problem was that the exclude was coming first...changing this from an include to filter works.