# How do I rsync only some files in some directories

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to sync all `*.jpg` files from `/var/www/data/models/days/` + some other directories from `/var/www/data` root.

I do:

`rsync -az --delete --include='/models' --include='*.jpg' --exclude='*' $SRC::/var/www/data /var/www/data`

but it doesn't sync anything. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I don't want to change the source or target to include /models/days as I need some other directories with the same filename matching (`*.jpg`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've included `/models` in the traversal, but none of its subdirectories. If a directory is excluded, rsync doesn't traverse it, so none of its contents can be included.

Use `--include='*/'` to include all subdirectories, and `-m` to not copy directories that would end up empty. For more information, see [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503)

Answer (score 0):

Your `--include` option needs to take account of leading subdirectory names.  Try using `**.jpg` instead: the rsync-specific `**` operator matches slashes as well as other characters.

Comment: `*.jpg` matches files in subdirectories as well: if there's no `/` in the pattern, it's matched against the basename of the file. `/*.jpg` would only match files at the toplevel. `**.jpg` is synonymous with `*.jpg`.