# rsync only subdirectories and content

Tags: files, directory, rsync

I have a directory that contains a number of files and subdirectories. See below:

```
baseDir
  bad1
  bad2
  subDir1
    file1
  subDir2
    file1
```

I would like to rsync the contents of baseDir without rsyncing bad1 and bad2.

resulting in

```
targetDir
  SubDir1
    file1
  SubDir2
    file1
```

I don't care if it takes two commands but how do I do it?

Comment: The solution depends on whether all files are known and static or new files may appear but shall be excluded, too.

Comment: The files are known now. But at some point in the future more may be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either include the desired directories and their parent and exclude everything else, or exclude the bad directories. Note that order matters: rsync decides what to do with a file from the first matching pattern (so for example anything after `--exclude=*` is effectively ignored). Note also that excluding a directory prevents it not only from being copied but also from being traversed, so this effectively excludes everything below it. See [this rsync filter primer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) for more information.

```
rsync --include='/' --include='/subDir***' --exclude='*' baseDir/ targetDir/
rsync --exclude='/bad*' baseDir/ targetDir/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--exclude-from` option of `rsync` to define whatever you do not want to include to sync

For Example:

```
 #cat exclude.txt 
  baseDir/bad1
  baseDir/bad2

 #rsync --exclude-from=exclude.txt -avr source_dir_path destination_dir_path
```

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` will take wildcards as arguments to the `--exclude` options so you can do something like this:

```
$ pwd
$ /some/dir

$ rsync -avz baseDir/ --exclude 'bad[1,2]' targetDir/.
```

For example:

```
$ rsync -avz baseDir/ --exclude 'bad[1,2]' targetDir/.
sending incremental file list
./
subDir1/
subDir1/file1
subDir2/
subDir2/file1

sent 185 bytes  received 61 bytes  492.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```