# Rsync include exclude

Tags: rsync

I know there are a billion questions of this out there. But I'm positive I have tried many of them and i am not able to make this work, so please, don't just mark this as duplicate

I have a file system looking like

```
1_counts/
|_________sample1/
          |__________boring_file1
          |__________boring_file2
          |__________boring_dir1/
                     |__________boring_file1
                     |__________boring_file2
          |__________dir/
                     |__________boring_file1
                     |__________boring_file2
                     |__________another_dir/
                                |__________file1
                                |__________file2
                                |__________file3
                                |__________boring_dir/
                                           |__________boring_file
                                |__________boring_file.RData
```

And I have several "sample" directories.

I need to sync file 1, 2 and 3 on `another_dir/` . I want to keep the file structure (I dont have the sub/directories in the destination), I just dont want to copy everything.

I started by trying to get everything under `dir/another_dir`:

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/" \
--exclude="*" 1_counts/* .
```

This doesnt return any files with the message `[sender] hiding directory sample_1 because of pattern *`. Same with

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="*" 1_counts/* .
```

This option (here on referred as **solution 1**) retrieved all contents in `dir/another_dir/`:

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

Tbh, I guessed it. I have no idea why I need `*/*` for the exclude.

If I try

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

I get only the `dir/another_dir` directories, not the contents. As expected.

And if i do

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/*" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

I get only the `dir/` directories, no contents. I guess this is also expected (Second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952000/using-rsync-include-and-exclude-options-to-include-directory-and-file-by-pattern/9952100)) but I am confused why i dont get `another_dir`s also... A mystery.

**Anyway**, now I can use solution 1 to copy everything from `1_counts/sample1/dir/another_dir`. Now I'm trying to exclude the boring_file.RData and `dir/another_dir/boring_dir`.

I tried

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="*.RData" \
--exclude="boring_dir/" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

This doesn't work. Everything is still included. I thought it was something to do with the path, so i also tried

```
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="dir/another_dir/*.RData" \
--exclude="dir/another_dir/boring_dir/" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

Doesn't work either. I'm running out of options and I'm confused on why some parts of this works...

I would really appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you are very close to the solution:

```bsh
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="*.RData" \
--exclude="boring_dir/" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

The thing is that `rsync` [uses the first matching pattern](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#FILTER_RULES), so by including everything under `another_dir`, you're effectively including the boring stuff and .RData files. You only have to change the order of the filter rules:

```bsh
rsync -r -v --dry-run --include="dir/" \
--exclude="*.RData" \
--exclude="boring_dir/" \
--include="dir/another_dir/***" \
--exclude="*/*" 1_counts/* .
```

Because order matters, [people put rules to exclude files by extension at the beginning](https://superuser.com/a/105236/713714), and [rules to exclude all at the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81089/297659).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved it. And now I kinda understand what is going on :-).