# rsync include-from exlcude-from with including subdir but excluding dirs above

Tags: rsync

I try to use rsync with `--include-from` and `--exclude-from` options.

I have a directory structure like:
`/docs/domain-[a-z]/templates`

Now I want to sync `templates` only if something is in there.
Further do not want to sync anything like
`/docs/domain-a` and
`/docs/domain-b`
if `templates` is empty.

I thought it would work if I exclude `/docs/domain*` and include `**/templates` but this is not working.

Should this work at all? Or is this just a problem of my rsync version 3.0.4 on SLES 11SP3

To clarify it

Source Dir

```
/docs/
/docs/anydomain/templates
/docs/anydomain/other
/docs/domain_blah/
/docs/domain_blah/tmp/
/docs/domain_blub/
/docs/domain_blub/tmp/
/docs/domain_blub/templates/anyfiles
/docs/domain_blob
/docs/ohter
/other
```

So I just want to sync the `/domain_blub/templates` if there is something inside `templates` and leave all the `/docs/domain_blub/tmp` and other files away
But I too want to sync contents from `/docs/anydomain/` or `/docs/other` and even `/other`

The target structure looks the same but there might be more domains set up which shouldn't be deleted or changed. It could look like this

```
/docs/
/docs/anydomain/templates
/docs/anydomain/other
/docs/domain_balah/
/docs/domain_balah/tmp/
/docs/domain_aaaa/
/docs/domain_aaaa/tmp/
/docs/domain_blah/
/docs/domain_blah/tmp/
/docs/domain_blub/
/docs/domain_blub/tmp/
/docs/domain_blub/templates/anyfiles
/docs/domain_blob
/docs/ohter
/other
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether what you want to do can be done purely with rsync, or whether it needs a few shell commands to pave the way. You didn't provide enough information about what you're trying to do. What do your source and destination look like?

Comment: Does my clarification above help, or do you need more insights?

Comment: It's now clear, I voted to reopen. In the meantime, [this guide](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) may help. Note that the order of exclude/include is important.