# rsync: mix exclude and include filters

Tags: rsync

The following pattern copies the .pdf files from source to destination, working fine.

```
rsync -rv --include="*.pdf" --include="*/" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs /source/ ~/destination/
```

but I want to exclude the files which contains web in file name is not working it is even copying the file web_profile.pdf file to the destination, why it is so.

```
rsync -rv --include="*.pdf" --include="*/" --exclude="*web*.pdf" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs /source/ ~/destination/
```

Also I'm not clear about the excluding particular directory like `**/` (mean 2 stars and single star).

Can someone please clear my doubts regarding pattern matching in rsync.

`--include="*.pdf"` matches `*pdf`, if I want to exclude some directory like `../web-info/..pdf`, how do I do it?

Comment: See [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only)

Answer (score 6):

The order of `--include` and `--exclude` options is relevant.

You are first including all `*.pdf` files, the later exclusion of `*web*.pdf` never applies because of this. Note also that include/exclude patterns apply to node names (files, directories, etc.) and not to pathnames, unless you have a `/` or `**` in the pattern; so excluding `*web*.pdf` wouldn't exclude `...web.../...pdf` anyway.

If you want all PDFs but not those under directories matching `*web*` then this should work:

```
rsync -rv --exclude "*web*/" --include="*.pdf" --include="*/" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs /source/ ~/destination/
```

This will prevent rsync recursing into directories matching `*web*`, include all `*.pdf` files, include all other directories, exclude all other files.

Using a `**` in the pattern might also work, although I prefer the above solution:

```
rsync -rv --exclude "**web*.pdf" --include="*.pdf" --include="*/" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs /source/ ~/destination/
```

Comment: Thank you very much wurtel, you cleared my doubts. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Thank you. It is so helpful for me.