# Copy .txt files in a certain directory

Tags: shell, command-line, filenames, wildcards, file-copy

I have an issue in copying my file in my directories.

I have `.txt` and `.jpeg` files in a lot of directories, and I want to copy only the `.txt` files according to the directory. For example, I have this:

```
direct/direct1
direct/direct2

direct1:
 file.txt
 file2.txt
 file.jpeg
 file2.jpeg

direct2:
 file3.txt
 file4.txt
 file3.jpeg
 file4.jpeg
```

in my copy command I need only the `.txt` files from each directory

Comment: Where do you want to copy them to?

Comment: You mean `cp direct/direct*/*.txt /destination` or `printf '%s\0' direct/direct*/*.txt | pax -rw0 /destination` ?

Comment: in another directory

Comment: You might use find: `find /path/to/direct -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} /destination` \;

Comment: @lambert I would not  use `\;` but `+` in that command

Comment: @Anthon, If you use `+` instead of `\;` you are not able to specify a target directory. The `cp` command will not take multiple sources. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Lambert I correct you: `mkdir tmp; cd tmp; touch a b c d; mkdir t; cp a b c d t; ls t;  ` shows  `a b c d`

Comment: @Anthon, thanks, I tested the suggested `+` before and it does not work in my case: `mkdir s; find t/ -exec cp {} s +` gives me: `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Comment: In that case I think that `find /path/to/direct -name "*.txt" | xargs | xargs -I{} cp {} /destination` works better than using the `+` option. BTW, I found a confirmation to your correction in the manual of cp: `Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.` I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy all the `.txt` files in a directory, use a [wildcard pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)):

```
cp direct/direct1/*.txt target
```

This copies all the `.txt` files that are in the directory `direct/direct1` to the directory `target` (which must already exist).

You can pass multiple patterns to copy files from multiple directories:

```
cp direct/direct1/*.txt direct/direct2/*.txt target
```

If you want to copy the `.txt` files from all the subdirectories of `direct`, you can use a wildcard for the directory as well:

```
cp direct/*/*.txt target
```

If you only want to copy from certain directories, you can use a wildcard pattern that matches only these directories. For example, if `direct` has four subdirectories `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `qux` and you only want to copy files from `bar` and `baz`, you can use

```
cp direct/ba?/*.txt target
```

None of the examples so far copy files from `direct` itself, or from subsubdirectories of `direct`. If you want to copy the `.txt` files from `direct`, you need to include it in the list, e.g.

```
cp direct/*.txt direct/*/*.txt target
```

If you want to copy files from `direct`, all of its subdirectories, all of their subdirectories, and so on recursively, you can use the `**` wildcard, if your shell supports it. It works out of the box in zsh, but in [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), you need to enable it first with `shopt -s globstar`.

```
cp direct/**/*.txt target
```

Note that all the files are copied into `target` itself, this does not reproduce the directory structure. If you want to reproduce the directory structure, you need a different tool, such as [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) ([tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503)) or [pax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_(Unix)).

```
rsync -am --include='*.txt' --include='*/' --exclude='*' direct/ target/
cd direct && pax -rw -pe -s'/\.txt$/&/' -s'/.*//' . target/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` to only select the `.txt files from under some directory:

```
find direct/direct? -name "*.txt"
```

this would print out all the files, so you can check you got what you wanted, and not too much is going to be selected. The `*.txt` has to be quoted, otherwise the shell will try expand this to `.txt` files in the current directory.

As for the copying, you want to do (most often) one of two things: preserve the path under direct to the `.txt` file or not. To preserve it use:

```
find direct/direct? -name "*.txt" -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 target_directory
```

to copy all the `.txt` files into one target directory use something similar to what @lambert suggested:

```
find direct/direct? -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} target_directory +
```

(using `+` instead of `\;` is more efficient as multiple filenames are passed to a single `cp` when `+` is used instead of invoking a `cp` for every single file when using `\;`)

For the second command `-print0` is not necessary to handle paths with special characters the filename that replace `{}` are properly separated by the way `cp` is invoked.