# Rsync specific files only from root and subdirectories

Tags: rsync

I have files in a directory structure like this:

```
/books/a.epub
/books/sub/b.epub
/books/test/c.epub
```

I would like to find all *.epub files in root (/books/) and subdirectories (/books/*/) and use rsync to copy only *.epub files to a remote directory.

So far I tried:

```
rsync -av  --include='*.epub' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /media/share/Books/ /home/user/docker/calibre/books/
```

But it is syncing directories as well.

Output should be look like this:

```
/a.epub
/b.epub
/c.epub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy only directories with .mp3 files with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217922/copy-only-directories-with-mp3-files-with-rsync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `find` and `xargs` available, you could do this:

```sh
find . -type f -iname "*.epub" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rsync -aPEmivv "{}" "/destination/directory"
```

And if you don't want to use `xargs`:

```sh
find . -type f -iname "*.epub" -exec rsync -aPEmivv "{}" "/destination/directory" \;
```

*(both variants are to be run inside your `/books/` directory)*

whether, the `-a` option in `rsync` is what you want, as that implies `-rlptgoD` (recursive, symlinks, pres. permissions, preserve times, preserve owner, preserve group, preserve device files), is your decision, though.

Note that when piping file names to another program, it is advisable to use null-delimited strings (`-print0` switch in `find`, and `-0` in `xargs` and `rsync` for null-delimited input), so that special characters in filenames don't become problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple levels to iterate through? If not?

```
rsync -aP  books/*/*.epub books/*.epub /home/user/movedbooks/.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` utility can read pathnames from a file or an input stream.  You may use `find` to find the files you'd like to copy and then copy these with `rsync`.

We will be assuming that you'd like to recursively search the directory `/media/share/Books` for any regular file whose name matches the shell globbing pattern `*.epub`.  Any found file matching these criteria should be copied to the single directory `/home/user/docker/calibre/books` without creating the corresponding directory structure found at the source hierarchy:

```bsh
find /media/share/Books -type f -name '*.epub' -print0 |
rsync   --from0 --files-from=-  \
        --archive --no-relative \
        / /home/user/docker/calibre/books
```

The way we're using `find` above assumes that it supports the non-standard but commonly implemented `-print0` predicate.  If it does not, you may replace `-print0` with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`.

Note the options used with `rsync` above.  The `--from0` option makes `rsync` interpret the stream of data read with `--files-from` as a nul-delimited list of pathnames. The `-` used with `--files-from` means "read from the standard input stream," i.e., from the `find` command. We use the `--archive` option (`-a`) to copy/sync as much metadata as possible with each file and `--no-relative` (`--no-R`) to discard the directory path component of the read pathnames.

The source directory used with `rsync` is `/` since the pathnames that we read from `find` are relative to the root directory.

This pipeline executes `rsync` a single time and safely passes the pathnames between `find` and `rsync`.  You only need to be aware that `rsync` will resolve name collisions by simply ignoring other files with the same names as files already listed.

---

You could also call `rsync` directly from `find` using `-exec`, but to make it a bit more efficient, we can use `find` to find directories and then call `rsync` to sync all the `*.epub` files in each.

```bsh
find /media/share/Books -type d -exec sh -c '
        for dirpath do
                rsync   --archive       \
                        --include="*.epub" --exclude="*"        \
                        "$dirpath/" /home/user/docker/calibre/books
        done' sh {} +
```

We're doing something similar here to what you tried but explicitly disallowing recursion by excluding directories from being processed. Instead of recursing with `rsync` we are outsourcing that to `find`.