# How to find all files matching (or not matching) a specific pattern in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell, files, find

How do I find all files in a folder and its subfolders terminated with 3 digits and move them to a new place while keeping the directory structure?

Alternatively, how can I find all files whose names don't end with three digits?

Comment: By “keeping the structure” do yo mean moving into subdirectories, recursively?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, _all files matching or not matching a pattern_ = all files.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Yes, keep the directory tree, e.g. move /old/a/a001 to /new/a/a001, /old/a/b/b012 to /new/a/b/b012

Comment: @don_crissti  hehe... two independent cases they are. Maybe it's clearer to say "matching (or not matching)". In fact, what I wanna do now is to remove all files not ended with 3 digits, the same effect as moving all files ended with 3 digits and deleting all old files.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2161

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping the structure"? Aren't all files in a single folder? Could you give an example?

Comment: @terdon referring to "the structure", I mean the tree of subdirectories and files. Not all files in a single folder.

Comment: Ah, right. Updated my answer then, but I'd use alienth's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much cleaner solution, based on an answer linked by @don_crissti. ([Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only))

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --include='*[0-9][0-9][0-9]' --include='*/' --exclude '*' /tmp/oldstruct/ /tmp/newstruct/
```

And the negation:

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --exclude='*[0-9][0-9][0-9]' /tmp/oldstruct /tmp/newstruct/
```

---

Original answer:

This should do it. It will find any file in the structure you `cd` into ending in 3 digits, create a destination folder in the `/tmp/newstruct`, and move the file.

```
cd /tmp/oldstruct
find ./ -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[0-9]\\{3\\}' | 
  while read i; do 
    dest=/tmp/newstruct/$(dirname $i)
    mkdir -vp $dest
    mv -v $i $dest
  done
```

I'd recommend prepending the `mkdir` and `mv` with `echo` before you actually run it, just to ensure it does what you're expecting.

To negate the 3 digits, simply place do `! -regex` instead.

---

Here is a simpler method which relies upon rsync. However, it does call `rsync` for every file it finds, so definitely not very efficient.

```
find ./ -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[0-9]\{3\}' --exec rsync -av --remove-source-files --relative {} /tmp/newstruct
```

Comment: The indent for while..done is necessary?

Comment: For this setup, yes. Although you might be able to find something that won't require loops by using a combination of `--include` and `--exclude` flags with `rsync`.

Comment: `$ls -R
.:
a001  aaa  b

./b:
b001  bbb  c

./b/c:
c001  ccc
$ find ./ -regextype posix-basic ! -regex '.*[0-9]\{3\}' -print | while read i; do d=/tmp/newstruct/$(dirname $i); mkdir -vp $d;  mv -v $i $d; done
mkdir: created directory ‘/tmp/newstruct’
mv: cannot move ‘./’ to ‘/tmp/newstruct/./.’: Device or resource busy
‘./b’ -> ‘/tmp/newstruct/./b’
mv: cannot stat ‘./b/c’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘./b/c/ccc’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘./b/bbb’: No such file or directory
‘./aaa’ -> ‘/tmp/newstruct/./aaa’
`

Comment: Ah, since you're negating, it's trying to move the directories as well. Add `-type f` to the find params.

Comment: I didn't notice the '!' ...... Perfect now!!!

Comment: @alienth: You disuse find’s `-exec` because of overhead? Or?

Comment: Didn't use `-exec` because I couldn't easily think of a way to duplicate the structure. Specifically the parts where I'm fetching the `dirname` and creating that directory. I could be missing something, tho.

Comment: @don_crissti  there is no problem. I didn't mean **ONLY** three digits.

Comment: BTW, `find` finds the regexp in the full path but not the filename only? I found `'.*[0-9]\{3\}' ` matches filename like `111` and the output filename is ./111

Comment: Without the `-type f`, the find will match directory names ending in 3 digits (not sure that is what you're referring to, tho).

Comment: @don_crissti Came up with an `-exec` solution which relies on `rsync` and added it above. Although that's a lot of `rsync` calls, potentially.

Comment: @don_crissti Just read up on that, and it is likely a better answer. One thing I'm trying to figure out on it is the regex syntax of `--include`, which isn't included in that answer. The `rsync` docs don't seem to indicate that it supports quantifiers?

Comment: @don_crissti yeah, looks as though quantifiers aren't supported. Not a big issue for this solution, though. Answer updated.

Comment: Please don't add _edit N_ to your answer. Just edit it. We don't need to know the history. Think of this site as a wiki, other people will read this answer and they don't need to know that it has gone through N revisions.

Comment: Also, please note that your `find` approach will fail if any of your file names contain newlines or glob characters. There's no need to loop over `find'`s output, you can use `-exec` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with bash :

```bash
## Make ** match all files and 0 or more dirs and subdirs
shopt globstar
## Iterate over all files and directories
for f in **; do 
    ## Get the name of the parent directory of the 
    ## current file/directory
    dir=$(dirname "$f"); 
    ## If this file/dir ends with 3 digits and is a file
    if [[ $f =~ [0-9]{3} ]] && [ -f "$f" ]; then 
        ## Create the target directory
        mkdir -p targetdir1/"$dir"
        ## Move the file
        mv "$f" targetdir1/"$f" 
    else 
        ## If this is a file but doesn't end with 3 digits
        [ -f "$f" ] && 
        ## Make the target dir
        mkdir -p targetdir2/"$dir" &&
        ## Move the file
        mv "$f" targetdir2/"$f" 
    fi 
done
```

Comment: @don_crissti ah, yes, you may well be right. The OP also said that all files are in a folder so I'm not sure what they want. And thanks, second command fixed.

Comment: No problem. I had initially wanted to vote to close it as a dupe of the other one but due to the fact the question is quite confusing I ended up leaving just a comment (although it's almost a duplicate imo).