# rsync directory tree structure with restricted depth and exclude specific folders

Tags: rsync

I want to rysnc my folder and subfolder tree structure without their files but with a max depth of 3 (/folder1/folder2/folder3) and exclude specific folders (ex. cache/)

I have tried this command:

```
$ rsync -azv --include=*/ --exclude=* --exclude=cache/ --exclude=/*/*/*/ source/ destination/
```

but it is not working... it is copying all folders and subfolders; it does not respect the max depth and it is not excluding cache folder

Do it need to use another parameter to restrict the max depth of the rsyc; what is wrong with my existing parameters?

p.s. last time I asked this question, it was tagged as duplicate of 
[Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only)

It is not as it does not deal with max depth nor deal with rsync directory tree structure only. thx

Comment: It may not be a duplicate...but you need to read that other Q&A more carefully.  The most obvious mistake in your command is that you're not single quoting quoting your patterns to avoid shell expansion (e.g. `--exclude='/*/*/*/'`).

Comment: yup thx the Q&A is quite helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude the multi-level pattern before including `*/` as the latter means "include all directories", overriding the later exclude. You also need to add an extra level as `*/` indicates a directory and `/*/*/*/` hence means "exclude three or more levels.

The command becomes:

```
rsync -azv --exclude='/*/*/*/*/' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --exclude=cache/ source/ destination/
```

(as Wildcard already commented you must always quote or escape shell metacharacters.)

Comment: thx for the answer .. it works fine except that I had to put --exclude=cache/ at the beginning for it to work properly.. I'm not really sure why

Comment: Ah yes, the `--include='*/'` includes any `cache` directories before they're excluded (which as a result doesn't happen).

Answer (score 1):

To sync two directory trees while respecting the max depth limit of three subdirectories use:

```
rsync -avz /source/ /destination --exclude "/**/**/**/*" --exclude=cache
```

This will also exclude the directory called *cache* anywhere in the source path.