# Copy only certain file types from a folder structure to another

Tags: files, file-copy, recursive

I have a top folder with many sub-folders. It's named "a". There are many `.png` and `.jpg` files in there. I'd like to recursively copy "a" into a new folder "b", but only copy the `.png` and `.jpg` files. How do I achieve that?

Comment: `rsync -a --include='*.png'  --include='*.jpg' --include='*/' --exclude='*' a/ b/` If you want to prune empty dirs add the `-m` switch : `rsync -am ....`

Comment: Please specify whether you want to recreate the directory structure (including only the `jpg/png` files) under `b` or you just want to recursively search for `jpg/png` under `a` and copy them to `b` ?

Comment: If you want to copy the directory tree recursively, this is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only . If you want to put all the files directly under b, I can't find a duplicate. Which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find a \( -name "*.png" -or -name "*.jpg" \) -exec cp {} b \;
```

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally used `*.png` twice and forgot `.jpg`. This is what happens when I try to answer questions while listening to music. Thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: OK, I think I got it this time. I learned something new about `find` today. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: stick with `-o` instead of `-or`, it's more portable.

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Answer (score 4):

One-liner

```
cp $(find a -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png") b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in $(find a -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png")
do
  cp ${file} b/${file}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter if there are more file types, using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

```
cp -r source_directory/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} target_directory
```

This gives an error whenever a file of a type does not exist. see https://serverfault.com/a/153893
Add `2>/dev/null` to hide these errors
Add `|| :` to not cause an exit code

```
cp -r source_directory/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} target_directory 2>/dev/null || :
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash globstar with `cp --parents`:

```
shopt -s globstar
mkdir -p dest
cp --reflink=auto --parents **/*.jpg **/*.png dest/
```