# Rsync exclude folder

Tags: rsync

so it seems like there are others with the same problem, but I couldn't find the right solution for myself.
What I want to do:
Rsync all files with pattern *.log.* but exclude a directory

Here is my rsync command:

```
rsync --include=*/ --include=*.log.*  --exclude=* --exclude=folder1/ -armte "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@server:/path/log/ /tmp/rsynctest/
```

So in /path/log are multiple subfolders.
/path/log/folder0
/path/log/folder1
/path/log/folder2 
etc. 
 And I want to exclude one of them (folder1). But rsync is still syncing this folder. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: remove trailing `/` at folder1. use only `--exclude=folder1`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But unfortunately it doesent work. Its still getting synced

Comment: See our [generic guide](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-failing-to-find-files). Order matters: here the first include rule includes all directories. You need to move `--exclude=folder1/` first.

Comment: Thats it! Damn I should get that myself. Thanks anyway!