# How to rsync multiple source folders

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync multiple sources and I wonder the best way to achieve that.

e.g.

```
/etc/fstab
/home/user/download
```

I thought about 3 solutions :

- Solution 1

multiple call to rsync

```
rsync -a /etc/fstab bkp
rsync -a /home/user/download bkp
```

con : harder to have agreggated stat

- Solution 2

create a `tobackup` folder that contains symlink, and use `-L` options

```
sync -aL /home/user/tobackup bkp
```

con : content to backup must not contain symlinks

- Solution 3

move files into to backup and create symlink in original location

```
rsync -a /home/user/tobackup bkp
```

con : some manual config

Which one do you recommend ?

Is there a better way ?

Comment: remote source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817583/rsync-multiple-remote-directories-to-local-machine-preserving-directory-paths

Answer (score 106):

You can pass multiple source arguments.

```
rsync -a /etc/fstab /home/user/download bkp
```

This creates `bkp/fstab` and `bkp/download`, like the separate commands you gave. It may be desirable to preserve the source structure instead. To do this, use `/` as the source and use [include-exclude rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) to specify which files to copy. There are two ways to do this:

- Explicitly include each file as well as each directory component leading to it, with `/***` at the end of directories when you want to copy the whole directory tree:

  ```
  rsync -a \
      --include=/etc --include=/etc/fstab \
      --include=/home --include=/home/user --include='/home/user/download/***' \
      --exclude='*' / bkp
  ```
- Include all top-level directories with `/*/` (so that rsync will traverse `/etc` and `/home` when looking for files to copy) and second-level directories with `/*/*/` (for `/home/user`), but strip away directories in which no file gets copied. This is more convenient because you don't have to list parents explicitly. You could even use `--prune-empty-dirs --include='*/'` instead of counting the number of levels, but this is impractical here as rsync would traverse the whole filesystem to explore directories even though none of the include rules can match anything outside `/etc` and `/home/user/download`.

  ```
  rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs \
      --include='/*/' --include='/*/*/' \
      --include=/etc/fstab \
      --include='/home/user/download/***' \
      --exclude='*' / bkp
  ```

Comment: And you can do a dry run by adding `-n` to make sure the outcome is the desired result

Answer (score 50):

I really like Gilles' answer, however, I'd like to add that in my view the requirement to sync multiple folders while preserving the directory structure is best met by passing multiple source arguments in conjunction with the `--relative` option.

In this case, we could have something as follows:

```
rsync -aR /etc/fstab /home/user/download bkp
```

which would result in `bkp/etc/fstab` and `bkp/home/user/download`.

The best part about this is that (I believe since rsync v. 2.6.7) we can in essence control how much of the directory structure we want to replicate at the destination.
(See the documentation on the `--relative` option [here](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html#opt--relative))

So e.g. if we did this

```
rsync -aR /home/./user1/download /home/./user2/download bkp
```

we would end up with `bkp/user1/download` and `bkp/user2/download`.

Answer (score 23):

This also works - curly braces, containing comma separated list of sources.

```
rsync -vap --progress --stats root@server:{/etc,/root/backups,/home/ultralazer} /mnt/bigdrive
```

Somewhat similar to what happens when you invoke curly braces sytnax with cp and certain other utilities:

```
cp -vr /etc /root/backups /home/{ultralazer,zerocool} /mnt/bigdrive
```

Comment: This is a shell feature, it is not guaranteed to work. More information here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409065/how-does-curly-brace-expansion-work-in-the-shell