# How does curly brace expansion work in the shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, brace-expansion

The command `echo {1..3}-{1,2}` prints `1-1 1-2 2-1 2-2 3-1 3-2`. I understand the way those curly braces can be used. But what actually *are* they?

Is it the job of `sh` / `bash` to parse/expand them and deliver the expanded version to the executed program?

If so, what other tricks can it do and is there a specification?

Also, is there a name for it?

Is `ls *.txt` handled in a similar way internally?

Is there a way to achieve an n-times repetition of an argument? Like (not working, of course, only a concept): `cat test.pdf{*3}` ⇒ `cat test.pdf test.pdf test.pdf` ?

Comment: They are called brace expansion, obviously. It's one of several expansions done by `bash`. You can read on it in [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Comment: Thanks! Posted as answer, this could get a check mark :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called **brace expansion**.

It is one of several expansions done by `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh`, filename expansion `*.txt` being another one of them.  Brace expansion is not covered by the POSIX standard and is thus not portable.
You can read on this in [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

On @Arrow's suggestion: in order to get `cat test.pdf test.pdf test.pdf` with brace expansion alone, you would have to use this "hack":

```
#cat test.pdf test.pdf
cat test.pdf{,}

#cat test.pdf test.pdf test.pdf
cat test.pdf{,,}

#cat test.pdf test.pdf test.pdf test.pdf
cat test.pdf{,,,}
```

Some common uses:

```
for index in {1..10}; do
   echo "$index"
done

touch test_file_{a..e}.txt
```

Or another "hack" to print a string 10 times:

```
printf -- "mystring\n%0.s" {1..10}
```

---

Be aware that brace expansion in `bash` is done **before** parameter expansion, therefore a common mistake is:

```
num=10
for index in {1..$num}; do
   echo "$index"
done
```

(the `ksh93` shell copes with this though)

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the edit. For some reason I thought the question was `bash` specific.

Answer (score 2):

[PesaThe's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409071/116858) answer covers important aspects of the question. There are several things I want to add.

The asterisk in `ls *.txt` is handled by the shell and is therefore controlled by shell options which can be changed by shell built-ins. In this case, one can disable asterisk expansion by running `set -f` and enable it again by `set +f`.

Another thing is that anyone who wants to make the script portable should check the POSIX standard. For example `{1..9..2}` expands to `1 3 5 7 9` in `bash` 4 but does not expand in lower `bash` versions or in `sh`.