# Rsync: How do I sync only certain filetypes from certain directories?

Tags: rsync

I want to copy all image type files from a few directories to /images.
I want to copy all video type files from the same directories to /videos.
I want to exclude all dot directories and dot files (hidden files and directories).

Directory structure:

```
DCIM (GOOD)
DCIM/.thumbnails (BAD)
DCIM/AccessoryCamera (GOOD)
.cloudagent (BAD)
Pictures (GOOD)
Downloads (GOOD)
```

I am trying:

```
rsync -ravtz --progress --prune-empty-dirs --include "DCIM/" --include "Download/*" --include "Picture/" --include "*.jpg" --include "*.png" --include "*.gif" --include "*.nef" --exclude '"*"' --exclude '".*"' --exclude '"*/"' --exclude '".*/"' --exclude '"DCIM/.thumbnails/*' --log-file=/mm/rsync.log /mnt/S8/sdcard/ '/mm/images'

rsync -ravtz --progress --prune-empty-dirs --include "DCIM/" --include "Download/*" --include "Picture/" --include "*.mov" --include "*.mpeg" --include "*.mpg" --include "*.mp4" --exclude '"*"' --exclude '".*"' --exclude '"*/"' --exclude '".*/"' --exclude '"DCIM/.thumbnails/*' --log-file=/mm/rsync.log /mnt/S8/sdcard/ '/mm/videos'
```

Comment: Can you give more information on what is not working as expected?

Comment: Why are you doubly quoting  `'"*"'` and so on? This should just be `'*'`.

Answer (score 4):

See [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) for more explanations on how to build an rsync filter. The general idea is to include what you need (including any directories leading to what you need) and exclude the rest at the end.

```
rsync -az --progress --prune-empty-dirs \
    --exclude '.*' \
    --include "/DCIM" --include "/Download" --include "/Picture" --exclude '/*' \
    --include "*.jpg" --include "*.png" --include "*.gif" --include "*.nef" \
    --include '*/' --exclude '*' \
    --log-file=/mm/rsync.log /mnt/S8/sdcard/ '/mm/images'
```

1. Exclude all dot files.
2. Include some directories and exclude everything else at the top level.
3. Include the file types you want.
4. Include all directories (except the ones already excluded at the top level) and exclude everything else.

Comment: This is still including all files.  .mp4 files are being backed up with this command for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Create a text file that houses the directories that you want to synchronize from your device:

`./input_dirs`

Contents of `./input_dirs`:

`./DCIM
./Pictures
./DCIM/AccessoryCamera
./Downloads`

Use the  `--files-from=./input_dirs.txt` param to load the directories in question into RSYNC

**(2)** Leverage the `--filter='dir-merge ./filter_file'` param to load the extension filters that you want.  (eg: *.png *.gif *.jpg)

Contents of `./filter_file`:

`+ *.png
+ *.jpg
+ *.gif
- /*`

**(3)** I just ran this as a test on a Linux Sandbox server and it worked.  Note that the *only* files that should be copied are ***.png***, **.gif**, ***.jpg** :

Results:

`[root@localhost ~]# ls -Fal
total 1012
dr-xr-x---.  4 root root   4096 Jun  5 20:03 ./
dr-xr-xr-x. 26 root root   4096 May 30 15:16 ../
-rw-------.  1 root root   1219 May 30 15:04 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-------.  1 root root   7161 Jun  5 19:45 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     18 Apr 29  2010 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    176 Apr 29  2010 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    176 Apr 29  2010 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    100 Apr 29  2010 .cshrc
-rwxr--r--.  1 root root   9565 May 30 20:41 cve.sh*
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Jun  5 20:03 dest/
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  14704 Dec 27 12:40 epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    508 May 30 22:08 file1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    508 May 30 22:08 file2
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     29 Jun  5 20:03 filter_file
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      3 Jun  5 19:46 input_dirs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  28978 May 30 15:04 install.log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   7572 May 30 15:01 install.log.syslog
-rw-------.  1 root root     88 Jun  4 17:49 .lesshst
drwxr-----.  3 root root   4096 Jun  4 17:45 .pki/
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 624068 May 24 04:34 samba-4.4.4-14.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 266168 May 24 04:34 samba-libs-4.4.4-14.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    129 Apr 29  2010 .tcshrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      0 Jun  5 19:55 test.gif
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      0 Jun  5 19:55 test.jpg
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      0 Jun  5 19:54 test.png`

`[root@localhost ~]# rsync -av --dry-run --files-from=./input_dirs --filter='dir-merge ./filter_file' ./ ./dest`

`building file list ... done`


`./`


`test.gif
test.jpg
test.png`


`sent 92 bytes  received 24 bytes  232.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)`

Remove --dry-run to actually copy files.

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm getting (DRY RUN) even though there is no --dry-run option being used.

Comment: @RobCampbell That behaviour I can't explain. :-/

Comment: I want to include only one directory and exclude rest of all directory in `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua` file. Have an any idea?

Comment: Still haven't gotten this to work properly.

sync -av --dry-run --files-from=./input_dirs.txt --filter='dir-merge ./filter_file' /path/dir/ /dir/path/
building file list ... done

sent 75 bytes  received 12 bytes  174.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)

rsync -az --progress --prune-empty-dirs --dry-run --exclude '.*' --include "/DCIM" --exclude '/*' --include "*.mp4" --exclude '*/' --exclude '*' --log-file=rsync.log /path/dir/ /dir/path

building file list ... 
2 files to consider
./

There should be 6 files.