# How to use rsync to force all *.jar files to match?

Tags: rsync, file-copy, synchronization

I have a directory with many files in it.  The only ones I care about are those with the extension `.jar`.  However, there are other files in the directory as well.

I have a source directory with *only* `.jar` files.  I want to achieve the equivalent of:

```
rm destdir/*.jar
cp sourcedir/*.jar destdir
```

However, I want to do this without actually *removing* the files that are already there, if they are the right files already.

---

In other words, I want it to be possible to run a single command that will:

1. For any `.jar` files present in `sourcedir` but not in `destdir`, copy them over.
2. For any `.jar` files present in both `sourcedir` and `destdir`, ensure that the copy in `destdir` matches the copy in `sourcedir` and overwrite it if it doesn't.
3. For any `.jar` files present in `destdir` but *not* in `sourcedir`, delete the file.
4. For any other files present in `destdir` (without a `.jar` extension), ignore them—do not delete them or change them.

---

It *seems* that this should be possible with `rsync`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```bsh
rsync -av --include='*.jar' --exclude='*' --delete \
    sourcedir/ destdir/
```

The `-a` option is archive mode, it preserves things like links and timestamps (check the `man` page for a full explanation). The `-v` is for verbosity, remove if you don't care about logs.

That should handle your first three option. The `--delete` option will take care of your fourth requirement while ignoring excluded files.

If you wish to include directories that contain `.jar` files you can use

```bsh
rsync -av --include='*.jar' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --delete \
    sourcedir/ destdir/
```

Based on the answer located here, if you have further questions it should help you: [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only)