# How to tar a list of directories only if they exist

Tags: shell-script, shell, ls, tar

I have a list of directories that I want to archive. But sometimes they do not all exist.

I want to be able to create an archive by providing a list of directories, and it will only archive the existing ones, and ignore missing ones. (but should still fail if no directories exist)

This is useful for me since I am running some continuous integration and some of the processes create certain artifacts that I want to retain for the future in an archive, I know all the possible paths that can be created, but am not always sure which ones are created.

Let's say the possible paths are: `here_is_a_dir` `here_is_another_one` `yet_another_dir`

I usually create the archive with the following command:

`tar -czf archive.tgz here_is_a_dir here_is_another_one yet_another_dir`

Which of course will fail if any of the directories are missing.

Ideally, it should be a simple command, and not require a script to do.
(specifically, in my environment only `sh` is available, so I can't use any fancy shells like `bash` or others, but that is specific to my environment, and could change in the future, and answers using other shells are probably good too I think.)

Comment: You said below that Bash isn't an option in your environment. What shell do you have to use? Is ksh available? Or do you just have Busybox or some other POSIX sh?

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the question, i will also update the original post. Only `sh` is available to me at the moment. But that is a limitation that only affects my specific situation, answers using other shells are still good answers I think.

Comment: You may want to look up `cpio` for this.

Answer (score 9):

Using the output of `ls` is generally unwise and unsafe - remember that both spaces and newlines and other shell meta-characters are valid characters in a file or directory name.  It is possible to work around this problem in many cases, but doing so is usually more effort than just using the right tool for the job (i.e. `find`).

So, use `find` instead. For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name here_is_a_dir -o -name here_is_another_one \
  -o -name yet_another_dir \) -exec tar cfz archive.tgz {} +
```

This finds any of the matching directories (`-type d`) in the current directory (`.`) and uses them as arguments to the `tar` command.    The `\(` to `\)` is an expression where each of the sub-expressions are OR-ed together using `-o` (by default, find's predicates are AND-ed).   i.e. it reads as "maxdepth 1 AND type directory AND (dir1 OR dir2 OR dir3)".

Note that without the brackets to force precedence, it would be interpreted as "maxdepth 1 AND type directory AND dir1 OR (dir2 OR dir3)", which would not return the full list of all existing directories.  Mostly, it would return either nothing, or only dir3, depending on whether dir1 existed or not.

If you want it to find the sub-directories anywhere underneath the current directory, drop the `-maxdepth 1` argument.

If you want the directory matches to be case-insensitive, use `-iname` instead of `-name`.  Note that the argument to `-name` or `-iname` can be a pattern rather than a fixed string - this is useful if the desired directory names are very similar.  e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'dir[123]' -exec tar cfz archive.tgz {} +
```

The `-exec ....` works a lot like piping to `xargs`, but built in to `find`.  In fact, you could use `xargs` if you wanted to by replacing everything from `-exec` onwards with `-print0 | xargs -0 -r tar cfz archive.tgz`.  e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'dir[123]' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r tar cfz archive.tgz
```

(this uses a NUL character as the output separator, so it's as safe to use with dirnames that contain spaces etc as it is to use `-exec`.  The `-r` option tells xargs to do nothing if there is no input)

Comment: This is very good. It may be worth mentioning, for the `xargs` variant, that `-r` is a GNU extension (according to the man page).

Comment: @DavidConrad that's true.  These days, I assume a GNU environment unless explicitly stated otherwise (it **is** the most common *nix-like userland, so makes a reasonable default).   Not all `find` versions support `-print0` either, but you have to go pretty far back in history (paleo-unix :-) to find one that doesn't.  BTW, I noticed that `busybox` has been mentioned in other comments here - `man busybox` reveals that it supports `xargs -r`.  as does freebsd's version of `xargs` (a null option. not actually needed, it does that by default.  only for compatibilty with GNU).

Comment: Good to know about busybox. I wouldn't have even mentioned xargs -r except OP mentioned being so limited as to shell.

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`:

```
dirs_to_archive=(some/dir /some/other/dir and/more/dirs)
existing_dirs=($^dirs_to_archive(/N))
if (($#existing_dirs)); then
  tar -cf - -- $existing_dirs | xz > file.tar.xz
else
  echo >&2 Error: none of the dirs were found
fi
```

The POSIX equivalent (though note that neither `tar` nor `xz` are POSIX commands) would be something like:

```
# The list of dirs in "$@" (the only array in POSIX sh language)
set -- some/dir /some/other/dir and/more/dirs

for dir do
  # remove from the array the elements that are not directories like with
  # zsh's / glob qualifier above
  [ -d "$dir" ] && [ ! -L "$dir" ] && set -- "$@" "$dir"
  shift
done
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  tar -cf - -- "$@" | xz > file.tar.xz
else
  echo >&2 Error: none of the dirs were found
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use bash, then with extended globbing (`extglob`):

```
$ shopt -s extglob; set -x
$ tar -czf archive.tgz *(here_is_a_dir|here_is_another_one|yet_another_dir)
+ tar -czf archive.tgz
tar: no files or directories specified
```

And if one or more of those exist:

```
$ touch here_is_a_dir yet_another_dir
+ touch here_is_a_dir yet_another_dir
$ tar -czvf archive.tgz *(here_is_a_dir|here_is_another_one|yet_another_dir)
+ tar -czvf archive.tgz here_is_a_dir yet_another_dir
a here_is_a_dir
a yet_another_dir
```

(I have used `set -x` so you can see the results of the glob expansion.)

Comment: that would be very useful, unfortunately `bash` is not available to me in this environment. But the answer is still correct and gets my +1

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively easily using `ls` to make a list of existing directories, and then piping through `xargs` into the `tar` command.

**solution:**

`ls -d here_is_a_dir here_is_another_one yet_another_dir 2> /dev/null | xargs tar -czf archive.tgz`

**breakdown:**

- `ls -d` only list directories
- `here_is_a_dir here_is_another_one yet_another_dir` the list of directories to check for
- `2> /dev/null` pipe the stderr to /dev/null so we only get stdout output (no missing dirs)
- `| xargs` turns the list of existing directories from the previous command into arguments
- `tar -czf archive.tgz` make an archive using the arguments

Comment: Note that xargs tries to find out how many arguments it can provide to the given command. Under unfavorable circumstances this could be 1, resulting in `tar -czf archive.tgz` being started separately for each directory. In that case you would only have the last directory in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

One that should work with just POSIX sh (`tar.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

first=1
for dir in "$@"; do
        if [ "$first" ]; then  # this is a bit ugly
                set --
                first=
        fi
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
                set -- "$@" "$dir"
        fi
done
echo tar -czf archive.tar.gz "$@"    # remove that 'echo'
```

Test:

```
$ mkdir here_is_a_dir yet_another_dir
$ ./tar.sh here_is_a_dir here_is_another_one yet_another_dir
tar -czf archive.tar.gz here_is_a_dir yet_another_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [pax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_(Unix)), you can use it to filter what gets included in the archive. Pax is mandated by POSIX as a replacement for the historically diverse cpio and tar, but many Unix variants have resisted its adoption, and in particular BusyBox doesn't have it.

Pax has a file exclusion feature, even though it's rather hidden in the description. You can rename files with `-s`. If you rename a file to the empty string, it gets excluded. With multiple `-s` options, for each the first match applies and renaming `-s` filters are skipped. This way, you can build a series of include/exclude rules, [much like with rsync](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-failing-to-find-files). An include rule in Pax syntax is `-s'!REGEX!&!'` (rename to itself) and an exclude rule is `-s'!REGEX!!'` (rename to empty).

```
pax -w -x ustar \
    -s'!^\./here_is_a_dir$!&!' -s'!^\./here_is_a_dir/!&!' \
    -s'!^\./here_is_another_one$!&!' -s'!^\./here_is_another_one/!&!' \
    -s'!^\./yet_another_dir$!&!' -s'!^\./yet_another_dir/!&!' \
    . | gzip >archive.tgz
```

BSD tar has a similar `-s` option. On the other hand, GNU tar and BusyBox tar don't have any way to do this include/exclude gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably

```
find adir anotherdir yadir -maxdepth 0 2>&- | tar Tcf - my.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `tar` supports it, create an empty tar file, and append to it as necessary using `-r` instead of `-c`

```
touch foo.tar

for d in here_is_a_dir here_is_another_one yet_another_dir; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    tar -rf foo.tar "$d"
  fi
done
gzip foo.tar
```