# Rsync: Clone structure for specific pattern

Tags: rsync, recursive, pattern-matching

How can one recursively copy all files of a specific pattern (`*.tpl`) using `rsync`?

Example:

```
/etc/test.tpl
/etc/dir/test.tpl
/etc/dir/**/test.tpl
```

Comment: Another possible duplicate, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2161/100397

Answer (score 0):

One command that solves this is:

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --recursive --relative --prune-empty-dirs --include="**/" --include="*.tpl" --exclude="*" /source /dest/
```

- `--relative`: Recreate all parent folders.
- `--include="**/"`: The `**` part allows recursion for folders (`/`).
- `--include="*.tpl"`: The pattern.
- `--exclude="*"`: Exclude the rest.

So far, we have included the whole folder structure, albeit with empty folders.

- `--prune-empty-dirs`: Remove empty folders [from the list].